# Permisos para realizar llamadas compatible con Android 6.0 y versiones anteriores

Tags: android, android-intent, permisos

En mi app, estoy creando una `Activity` con varios `TextView` que recoge la información de una base de datos en `SQLite` integrada en mi app, y uno de los datos, es el teléfono.

Mi intención con este dato, era poder crear un botón en la misma `Activity`, que al pulsarlo, realizara la llamada al teléfono del registro de la BD que se esta mostrado en pantalla, pero me he topado con que para cada versión de Android se realiza de una forma, por ejemplo:

Para Android 5.0:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);         
intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Pero para Android 6.0 no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo y claro, no solo tiene que ser para la ultima versión, si no que tiene que ser compatible con las demás.

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo creo un permiso para poder realizar llamadas compatible con Android 6.0 y anteriores?**

Espero que me podáis echar una mano y un ejemplo. :)

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: En este link tienes la solución https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo te dejo el ejemplo del link [developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.htm](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html%20%E2%80%93)l que lo acabo de hacer aprovechando que yo también lo tendré que implementar.

**Pedir permisos solo a partir de 6.0:**

```
final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 0;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
        }
    }
}
```

**Recibir la respuesta del usuario:**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                callPhone();
            } else {
                System.out.println("El usuario ha rechazado el permiso");
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void callPhone() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Lo probé y va bien de todas formas ahora también probaré el ejemplo de @Elenasys.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Para aplicaciones con OS Android anteriores a 6.0 es suficiente con definir el permiso dentro de tu archivo   `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

---

#### Requerir permisos en Android 6.0 o posterior.

Este sería la forma de requerir [permisos](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) para poder realizar llamadas telefónicas en `Android 6.0` :

```
 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas telefónicas.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso!");
    }
```

Comment: Me funciona, pero la primera vez que lo ejecuto cuando me pregunta si quiero dar permisos la app se detiene.

Comment: Revisa en tu LogCat y agrega el mensaje, con gusto te ayudo a resolver el problema. @wasous