# Pedir permiso individual en Android 6+ M

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Estoy implementando el chequeo de permisos en tiempo de ejecución para `Android 6+/ Android M` más o menos entiendo el proceso:

- `checkSelfPermission` Para chequear el permiso:
- `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` Para saber si el usuario permite mostrar el dialogo de petición.
- `requestPermissions` Para mostrar el dialogo de petición.
- `onRequestPermissionsResult` Recibiendo la confirmación

Pero para hacerlo compatible en versiones inferiores de Android M, como se estructura, la acción a realizar donde se debe poner en `onRequestPermissionsResult` o en `checkSelfPermission`?

También teniendo en cuenta si el permiso es requerido para diferentes acciones.

Comment: Un manual de buenas prácticas https://labs.ribot.co.uk/exploring-the-new-android-permissions-model-ba1d5d6c0610#.nbwgipnhp

Comment: Para versiones anteriores a 6 no se dan los permisos al momento de instalar la aplicacion?

Comment: He encontrado esa librería simplifica el proceso https://github.com/pankaj89/PermissionHelper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes pedir todos los permisos cuando abran la app por primera vez o cuando lo requieras, yo por ejemplo tengo algo así para revisar si el permiso esta activo

```
public boolean checkAudioPermission(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

ahora si no esta activo para pedir que lo activen lo hago así:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
```

y para recibir el callback de la activación lo tengo así:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                //Aquí lo que se hace si aceptan el permiso

            } else {

                //Aquí lo que se hace si no lo aceptan
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora donde agregar esto? bueno yo lo hago en la actividad, o al menos me es mas fácil porque tengo una Actividad Base desde la cual heredan las demás.

Comment: Muy buenas @Bourne la comparación del sdk no seria mejor android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M?

Comment: Si tienes razón, buena observación

Comment: Debe ser desde *M no MR1*!

Comment: Corregido, gracias ;)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la clase Build, validando si la versión de tu OS es >= Android 6.0 (**[M](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#M)**) :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
}
```

En este caso únicamente revisas permisos para Android 6.0 o mayor, para versiones anteriores los permisos son definidos en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

Aquí hay algo importante, cual sería tu targetSDK?
Si defines en tu `build.gradle` API 23 o mayor debes considerar requerir los permisos como se realiza con Android 6.0+ si es que se encuentran en la lista

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups

Un ejemplo de como requerir los permisos se encuentra en esta respuesta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13445/95

Answer (score 0):

A partir de la respuestas y recursos que he encontrado por SO

He creado la siguiente clase para manejo de petición de recursos [Gist: permissionutil.java v:alpha](https://gist.github.com/webserveis/ebd0b13deff0eba826de402cbd9ffd16#file-permissionutil-java)

Su uso es muy fácil:

Con  `hasPermissions` se puede comprobar si el permiso está permitido o denegado
Con `requestPermission` **Crear copias para su personalización** se muestra el dialogo pero antes mostrando una snackbar.

```
if (PermissionUtil.hasPermissions(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Action for: Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS ");
} else {
    PermissionUtil.requestPermission(MainActivity.this,parentLayout,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, REQUEST_READ_CONTACT);
}
```

Para computar el resultado del permiso en  `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_READ_CONTACT: {

            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "REQUEST_READ_CONTACT Permission has been granted by user");
            } else if (PermissionUtil.shouldWeAskPermission(MainActivity.this,permissions[0])) {
                Log.w(TAG, "REQUEST_READ_CONTACT Permission has been denied by user");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Need user go to Settings device ");
            }
            return;
        }
        default: {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Y si alguna función nos da el siguiente error

Algunas funciones como getLastLocation de las GooglePlayServices dan el siguiente error:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly chreck to see if permission is available(with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`

Anotarla con `@SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})` si ya se ha verificado primero con `hasPermissions`

#### UPDATE

Usando la [librería PermissionHelper](https://github.com/pankaj89/PermissionHelper) hace más fácil la solicitud de los permisos

```
PermissionHelper permissionHelper;
...
permissionHelper = new PermissionHelper(this, new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
        PERM_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

permissionHelper.request(new PermissionHelper.PermissionCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionGranted() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionGranted() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionDenied() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionDenied() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionDeniedBySystem() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionDeniedBySystem() called");
    }
});
```

y el método `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (permissionHelper != null) {
        permissionHelper.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```