# Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )

Tags: android, alertdialog

Hola amigos lo que me sucede es que necesito leer la ruta de un archivo que se encuentra almacenado en la memoria de mi celular, ya tengo todo, lo que sucede es que en android 5.1 me corre bien sin problemas y me visualiza el directorio y cuando lo corro en un android 6.0 no me muestra nada no se a que se deba pero les dejo las imagenes de la diferencia y el código si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.

En android 5.1 al correrlo.

[image: En android 5.1]

En android 6.0 al correrlo.

[image: En android 6.0]

SimpleFileDialog.java

```
public class SimpleFileDialog
{
private int FileOpen     = 0;
private int FileSave     = 1;
private int FolderChoose = 2;
private int Select_type = FileSave;
private String m_sdcardDirectory = "";
private Context m_context;
private TextView m_titleView1;
private TextView m_titleView;
public String Default_File_Name = "default.txt";
private String Selected_File_Name = Default_File_Name;
private EditText input_text;

private String m_dir = "";
private List<String> m_subdirs = null;
private SimpleFileDialogListener m_SimpleFileDialogListener = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> m_listAdapter = null;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Callback interface for selected directory
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public interface SimpleFileDialogListener
{
    public void onChosenDir(String chosenDir);
}

public SimpleFileDialog(Context context, String file_select_type, SimpleFileDialogListener SimpleFileDialogListener)
{
    if (file_select_type.equals("FileOpen"))          Select_type = FileOpen;
    else if (file_select_type.equals("FileSave"))     Select_type = FileSave;
    else if (file_select_type.equals("FolderChoose")) Select_type = FolderChoose;
    else Select_type = FileOpen;

    m_context = context;
    m_sdcardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    m_SimpleFileDialogListener = SimpleFileDialogListener;

    try
    {
        m_sdcardDirectory = new File(m_sdcardDirectory).getCanonicalPath();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// chooseFile_or_Dir() - load directory chooser dialog for initial
// default sdcard directory
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public void chooseFile_or_Dir()
{
    // Initial directory is sdcard directory
    if (m_dir.equals(""))   chooseFile_or_Dir(m_sdcardDirectory);
    else chooseFile_or_Dir(m_dir);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// chooseFile_or_Dir(String dir) - load directory chooser dialog for initial
// input 'dir' directory
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public void chooseFile_or_Dir(String dir)
{
    File dirFile = new File(dir);
    if (! dirFile.exists() || ! dirFile.isDirectory())
    {
        dir = m_sdcardDirectory;
    }

    try
    {
        dir = new File(dir).getCanonicalPath();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        return;
    }

    m_dir = dir;
    m_subdirs = getDirectories(dir);

    class SimpleFileDialogOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
        {
            String m_dir_old = m_dir;
            String sel = "" + ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getAdapter().getItem(item);
            if (sel.charAt(sel.length()-1) == '/')  sel = sel.substring(0, sel.length()-1);

            // Navigate into the sub-directory
            if (sel.equals(".."))
            {
                m_dir = m_dir.substring(0, m_dir.lastIndexOf("/"));
            }
            else
            {
                m_dir += "/" + sel;
            }
            Selected_File_Name = Default_File_Name;

            if ((new File(m_dir).isFile())) // If the selection is a regular file
            {
                m_dir = m_dir_old;
                Selected_File_Name = sel;
            }

            updateDirectory();
        }
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = createDirectoryChooserDialog(dir, m_subdirs,
            new SimpleFileDialogOnClickListener());

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            // Current directory chosen
            // Call registered listener supplied with the chosen directory
            if (m_SimpleFileDialogListener != null){
                {
                    if (Select_type == FileOpen || Select_type == FileSave)
                    {
                        Selected_File_Name= input_text.getText() +"";
                        m_SimpleFileDialogListener.onChosenDir(m_dir + "/" + Selected_File_Name);}
                    else
                    {
                        m_SimpleFileDialogListener.onChosenDir(m_dir);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);

    final AlertDialog dirsDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

    // Show directory chooser dialog
    dirsDialog.show();
}

private boolean createSubDir(String newDir)
{
    File newDirFile = new File(newDir);
    if   (! newDirFile.exists() ) return newDirFile.mkdir();
    else return false;
}

private List<String> getDirectories(String dir)
{
    List<String> dirs = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        File dirFile = new File(dir);

        // if directory is not the base sd card directory add ".." for going up one directory
        if (! m_dir.equals(m_sdcardDirectory) ) dirs.add("..");

        if (! dirFile.exists() || ! dirFile.isDirectory())
        {
            return dirs;
        }

        for (File file : dirFile.listFiles())
        {
            if ( file.isDirectory())
            {
                // Add "/" to directory names to identify them in the list
                dirs.add( file.getName() + "/" );
            }
            else if (Select_type == FileSave || Select_type == FileOpen)
            {
                // Add file names to the list if we are doing a file save or file open operation
                dirs.add( file.getName() );
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}

    Collections.sort(dirs, new Comparator<String>()
    {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2)
        {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    return dirs;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////                                   START DIALOG DEFINITION                                    //////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private AlertDialog.Builder createDirectoryChooserDialog(String title, List<String> listItems,
                                                         DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(m_context);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create title text showing file select type //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    m_titleView1 = new TextView(m_context);
    m_titleView1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //m_titleView1.setTextAppearance(m_context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    //m_titleView1.setTextColor( m_context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black) );

    if (Select_type == FileOpen    ) m_titleView1.setText("Open:");
    if (Select_type == FileSave    ) m_titleView1.setText("Save As:");
    if (Select_type == FolderChoose) m_titleView1.setText("Folder Select:");

    //need to make this a variable Save as, Open, Select Directory
    m_titleView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
   // m_titleView1.setBackgroundColor(-12303292); // dark gray  -12303292
    m_titleView1.setTextColor( m_context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white) );

    // Create custom view for AlertDialog title
    LinearLayout titleLayout1 = new LinearLayout(m_context);
    titleLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    titleLayout1.addView(m_titleView1);


    if (Select_type == FolderChoose || Select_type == FileSave)
    {
        ///////////////////////////////
        // Create New Folder Button  //
        ///////////////////////////////
        Button newDirButton = new Button(m_context);
        newDirButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        newDirButton.setText("New Folder");
        newDirButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v)
                                            {
                                                final EditText input = new EditText(m_context);

                                                // Show new folder name input dialog
                                                new AlertDialog.Builder(m_context).
                                                        setTitle("New Folder Name").
                                                        setView(input).setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                                {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                                                    {
                                                        Editable newDir = input.getText();
                                                        String newDirName = newDir.toString();
                                                        // Create new directory
                                                        if ( createSubDir(m_dir + "/" + newDirName) )
                                                        {
                                                            // Navigate into the new directory
                                                            m_dir += "/" + newDirName;
                                                            updateDirectory();
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            Toast.makeText( m_context, "Failed to create '"
                                                                    + newDirName + "' folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }).setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null).show();
                                            }
                                        }
        );
        titleLayout1.addView(newDirButton);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create View with folder path and entry text box //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    LinearLayout titleLayout = new LinearLayout(m_context);
    titleLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    m_titleView = new TextView(m_context);
    m_titleView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  //  m_titleView.setBackgroundColor(-12303292); // dark gray -12303292
    m_titleView.setTextColor( m_context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white) );
    m_titleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    m_titleView.setText(title);

    titleLayout.addView(m_titleView);

    if (Select_type == FileOpen || Select_type == FileSave)
    {
        input_text = new EditText(m_context);
        input_text.setText(Default_File_Name);
        titleLayout.addView(input_text);
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    // Set Views and Finish Dialog builder  //
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    dialogBuilder.setView(titleLayout);
    dialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(titleLayout1);
    m_listAdapter = createListAdapter(listItems);
    dialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(m_listAdapter, -1, onClickListener);
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    return dialogBuilder;
}

private void updateDirectory()
{
    m_subdirs.clear();
    m_subdirs.addAll( getDirectories(m_dir) );
    m_titleView.setText(m_dir);
    m_listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //#scorch
    if (Select_type == FileSave || Select_type == FileOpen)
    {
        input_text.setText(Selected_File_Name);
    }
}

private ArrayAdapter<String> createListAdapter(List<String> items)
{
    return new ArrayAdapter<String>(m_context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1, items)
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (v instanceof TextView)
            {
                // Enable list item (directory) text wrapping
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                tv.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                tv.setEllipsize(null);
            }
            return v;
        }
    };
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    AdapterContactos.customButtonListener {

TextView contenido;
ListView lista;
Button cargar,agregarTodos;

AdapterContactos adapter;
ArrayList<Contact> contactos;
ArrayList<Contact> contactos2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contenido = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcontenido);
    lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    cargar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btrecuperar);
    agregarTodos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btagregartodos);



    contactos = new ArrayList<>();
    contactos2 = new ArrayList<>();
    cargarDataBase();

    if(contactos2.isEmpty()){
        agregarTodos.setEnabled(false);
    }

    cargar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        String m_chosen;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Create FileOpenDialog and register a callback
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            SimpleFileDialog FileOpenDialog =  new SimpleFileDialog(MainActivity.this, "FileOpen",
                    new SimpleFileDialog.SimpleFileDialogListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onChosenDir(String chosenDir)
                        {
                            // The code in this function will be executed when the dialog OK button is pushed
                            m_chosen = chosenDir;

                            contenido.setText(m_chosen);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Archivo escogido File: " +
                                    m_chosen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

            //You can change the default filename using the public variable "Default_File_Name"
            FileOpenDialog.Default_File_Name = "";
            FileOpenDialog.chooseFile_or_Dir();

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        }
    });
}
```

Gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.carlos.lectura"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Es problema de permisos, aquí puedes obtener respuesta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23506/pedir-permiso-individual-en-android-6-m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Petición permisos **[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)**

Uno de los permisos que se requieren para **[Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)** es el de **[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)** (que implícitamente es también `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` ):

Lo debes definir en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

pero también debes requerir el permiso antes de tratar de leer el almacenamiento externo, llama este método:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Puedes validar llamar el metodo unicamente el sistemas operativos mayores o igual a Android 6.0 :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
     checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Elenasys eres grande! :D era justo lo que necesitaba y ya funciona

Comment: Hola Carlos, me da mucho gusto, Saludos!