# ¿Como copiar el contenido de una carpeta a otra?

Tags: java, android

**Hola a todos.**
He tratado de copiar los datos de una carpeta a otra mediante los datos de entra y salida implementando  este método:

```
    public boolean creaArchivo1(String ruta, InputStream is)
        throws IOException {

        final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(ruta)));
        byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        int bytesLeidos = 0;

        while ( (bytesLeidos = is.read(chunk)) > 0) {

            os.write(chunk, 0, bytesLeidos);
        }
        os.close();
        String si="si";

        boolean verdadero=true;
        return verdadero;

    }
```

**Pero  no copia los datos si saben cualquier otra forma o notan donde fallo.Por favor comunicármelo. Gracias.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a copiar contenido seguramente te refieres a el almacenamiento externo, primeramente es importante asignar el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Si usas Android 6.0+ debes requerirlos de esta forma:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24934/95

---

puedes realizar el copiado de un directorio hacia otra ruta mediante este método:

```
public void copiarDirectorio(File sourceLocation , File targetLocation) {
    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists() && !targetLocation.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("Error", "No puede crear directorio: " + targetLocation.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {
        File directory = targetLocation.getParentFile();
        if (directory != null && !directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("Error", "No puede crear directorio: " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);


        //Copa bits de inputStream to outputStream.
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();

        }catch(IOException ioe){
            Log.e("Error", "Error " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¿No te sirve esta sencilla solución? A través de las dos rutas de las carpetas (la de origen y la de destino) puedes copiar los datos/archivos de una carpeta a otra:

```
File origen = new File("C:\\prueba\\origen");
File destino = new File("C:\\prueba\\destino");
try {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(origen, destino);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Me funcionara si no fuera que es tuviera programando también con android y android no incluye esa clase.Muchas gracias.