# ¿Por qué me queda denegado, el permiso para archivo adjunto, usando Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app

últimamente que querido implementar en mi aplicación, **la opción de adjuntar una imagen a un correo electrónico mediante código de Java para Android**, utilizando "Intent", pero al momento de crear el correo, la aplicación de Gmail, me dice: Se denegó el permiso para el archivo adjunto.

La imagen la obtengo desde mi ImageView, lo guardo en canche, obtengo la ruta de donde se guardo, y le paso el Uri al Intent. Pues quería saber que mas le falta el código, para que pueda funcionar, por que ya intente varias formas.

**-Gracias**

Obtención de la imagen del ImageView:

```
 mImageProduct = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.product_image_view_order_editor);
 mImageProduct.buildDrawingCache(); 
 Bitmap imageProduct = mImageProduct.getDrawingCache();
```

Código del Intent:

```
private void composeEmail(String[] emailProvider, String quantityCurrent, String currentDay, String nameProduct, Bitmap imageProduct) {

    File file = new File(getCacheDir(), imageProduct + ".png");

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageProduct.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.e(OrderEditorActivity.class.getSimpleName(), file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        file = null;
    }

    String subject = getString(R.string.msg_subject);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailProvider);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, createdOrder(quantityCurrent, currentDay, nameProduct));
    if(file != null) {
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    }
    intent.setType("*/*");

    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.msg_error_email), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Error que se muestra en pantalla al momento de ejecutar el botón de enviar:

[image: Muestra del error en pantalla]

Comment: Ya revisast agregar los permisos manualmente si tienes android 6.0 o posterior. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android @Arielrios

Comment: Lo hice, pero aun me da el error

Comment: y ya revisaste el LogCat si despliega algún mensaje de error?

Comment: De parte de mi aplicación no. Todo va bien, solo la imagen no se quiere agregar

Comment: He visto cual es el problema , estas anexando el archivo desde tu storage interno, desde el caché.

Comment: ¿Como lo pondría en el externo?, si desde el caché lo hacia

Comment: copiarlo o generar el archivo al directorio externo, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail agregó algunas comprobaciones de seguridad a los archivos adjuntos que se reciben de un `intent`, cambia `startActivity` por `startActivityForResult`. Debería funcionar. Y no olvides los permisos en el Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Aun me lanza el error, ya teniendo los permisos ¿Debo sobrescribir `public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)` y `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` ?

Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Cambia esto: `if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } ` por esto: `if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent);
    } `

Comment: Si lo agregue con un **resquestCode: 225**, dado que me lo pide la función, pero aun no agrega la imagen. me sale el mismo mensaje de que se denegó el permiso

Comment: Prueba cambiando esto: `File file = new File(getCacheDir(), imageProduct + ".png");` por esto: `File file = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), imageProduct + ".png");`

Comment: La variable `context` de que tipo seria y que valor tendría, dado que no tengo esa variable, o ¿de donde sale?

Comment: Intenta estas dos formas: `File(getExternalCacheDir(), imageProduct + ".png");` || `File.createTempFile(context.getExternalCacheDir(), imageProduct + ".png");`

Comment: Al fin! Muchas muchas! Gracias :)


`File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), imageProduct + ".png");` 

Ese fue la linea que funciono al final

Comment: Para eso estamos, que gusto que te funcionó. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que al crear el archivo, estas usando [getCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir())

```
 File file = new File(getCacheDir(), imageProduct + ".png");
```

> [getCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()) Devuelve una instancia de File que representa un
>   directorio interno de los archivos temporales de caché de tu app.
>   Asegúrate de eliminar cada archivo cuando ya no sea necesario y de
>   implementar un límite razonable para la cantidad de memoria que se
>   utiliza en un momento determinado, por ejemplo, 1MB. Si el sistema
>   comienza a quedarse sin espacio de almacenamiento, es posible que
>   elimine tus archivos de caché sin previo aviso.

**El archivo lo generas en el directorio interno, para que se pueda anexar a tu email, debes realizar una copia al externo o bien generarlo en el directorio externo mediante  [getExternalCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir())**:

```
File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), imageProduct + ".png");
```

> [getExternalCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()): Devuelve la ruta absoluta al directorio
>   específico de la aplicación en el dispositivo de almacenamiento
>   compartido / externo principal donde la aplicación puede colocar los
>   archivos de caché que posee. Estos archivos son internos a la
>   aplicación y normalmente no son visibles para el usuario como medios.

Obviamente necesitas los **[permisos](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#GetWritePermission)** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: En mi caso, genero un archivo, y no necesito modificar los permisos para enviarlo por correo electronico. Eso si para evitar el error FileUriExposedException he tenido que agregar en OnCreate de la actividad:  StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());