# Error con el FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android, file

Estoy intentando guardar una imagen de un `ImageView` en la galería de mi dispositivo móvil y el problema está en que me crea todo el rato el directorio sobre el que quiero guardar la imagen y luego la ruta cuando voy a hacer el `FileOutputStream` me dice que no existe. Adjunto el código donde me está dando el fallo:

```
 public void SaveImage(Context context, Bitmap ImageToSave) {

    TheThis = context;
    NameOfFolder = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    String estado=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    Boolean sdDisponible=false;
    Boolean sdAccesoEscritura=false;

    if(estado.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        sdDisponible=true;
        sdAccesoEscritura=true;
        Log.v("IMAGEN","true todo");
    }else if(estado.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)){
        sdDisponible=true;
        sdAccesoEscritura=false;
    }else{
        sdAccesoEscritura=false;
        sdDisponible=false;
    }


    if(sdDisponible && sdAccesoEscritura) {
        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + NameOfFolder;
        String CurrentDateAndTime = getCurrentDateAndTime();
        File dir = new File(file_path);

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
            Log.v("IMAGEN","crea carpeta");
        }

        File file = new File(dir, NameOfFile + CurrentDateAndTime + ".jpg");
        Log.v("IMAGEN", "Pasa el file");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Log.v("IMAGEN", "Pasa el output");

            ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
            Log.v("IMAGEN", "Pasa el output2");
            fOut.flush();
            Log.v("IMAGEN", "Pasa el output3");
            fOut.close();
            Log.v("IMAGEN", "Pasa el output4");
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
            MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(file);
            Log.v("IMAGEN", "Pasa el output5");
            AbleToSave();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            UnableToSave();
            Log.v("IMAGEN", e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            UnableToSave();
            Log.v("IMAGEN", e.toString());
        }
    }else{
        UnableToSave();
    }

}
```

Paso la consola con el `Log`de hasta donde se ejecuta el código:

```
08-29 14:28:13.374 8582-8582/es.aandg.demo V/IMAGEN: true todo
08-29 14:28:13.386 8582-8582/es.aandg.demo V/IMAGEN: crea carpeta
08-29 14:28:13.386 8582-8582/es.aandg.demo V/IMAGEN: Pasa el file
08-29 14:28:13.409 8582-8582/es.aandg.demo V/IMAGEN: 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0Demo/IMG-2017-08-
    29_14-28-
    13.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `NameOfFile + CurrentDateAndTime + ".jpg"`? ¿No tendrá por casualidad algún carácter prohibido?

Comment: @SJuan76 el valor es `IMG-2017-08-29_14-28-13.jpg`. Si te fijas, esta en el logcat que el publico.

Comment: verificaste si existe la imagen en esa dirección? /storage/emulated/0Demo/IMG-2017-08-29_14-28-13.jpg

Comment: Un punto importante, el que `File.mkdirs()` no lance un exception no significa que los directorios estén creados; deberías comprobar el valor que devuelve. Y por lo que veo de la documentación de Android, no estás obteniendo el path de la forma recomendada: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas [mkdirs()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) para crear el directorio:

```
 dir.mkdirs();
```

y comentas que siempre lo esta creando, en realidad lo esta tratando de crear si no existe, e**l problema aquí es que seguramente no tienes los permisos necesarios, recuerda que el permiso [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) es indispensable.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

de hecho cuando tratas de salvar el archivo, guardarlo en la instancia `File`, este archivo no existe,

```
 FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

ya que no pudo ser creado, por esta razón tienes el mensaje de error:

> open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

---

Otra razón para que no pueda crear el archivo es  sin duda en donde lo estas generando, en este caso usas

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

por lo tanto se crearía dentro de:

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

Es importante agregar un "/" al final para crear correctamente la ruta del folder, de otra forma este también puede ser un problema, esta sería la solución.

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + NameOfFolder;
```

Como dato extra, puedes validar la creación del directorio de esta forma, ya que  [mkdirs()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) entrega `true` si se creo sin problema el directorio, en cualquier otro caso `false`:

```
  if (!dir.exists()) {
            String message = dir.mkdirs()?"Se creo carpeta correctamente!": "No se pudo crear =(";
            Log.v("IMAGEN","crea carpeta " + message);
        }
```

---

**Si usas Android 6.0 o posterior, la petición del permiso debe ser manual, ya que no es suficiente declararlo dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`**, puedes llamar este método en `onCreate()` para obtener los permisos:

```
private void revisaPermisosAlmacenamiento() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

revisa esta pregunta:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android)

Comment: Hola, el permiso está añadido, por eso también me resulta raro

Comment: ok usas sistema operativo 6 o mayor verdad? revisa la actualización de la respuesta.

Comment: acabo de añadirlo, pero vuelve al error original

Comment: @AdriánGarridoBlázquez no se si tu me diste calificación negativa  pero te puedo asegurar la información es útil, agregué otro detalle que seguramente es el problema si es que lo anterior quedó descartado, solo agrega "/" como separador:  String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + NameOfFolder; , agregue también como validar para mostrar si creo o no el directorio.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, esa era la cosa, ya funciona perfectamente, y no, no he sido yo el que te ha dado la puntuación negativa, faltaría más debido al trabajo que has hecho. Mil gracias :D

Comment: Excelente que pudiste resolver el problema Adrián, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Porque no pruebas a crear el fichero con el metodo openFileOutput :

```
 context.openFileOutput(FileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Mira en la documentación de android : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Así creas el archivo en el área privada de la aplicación