# Problema en el FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Deseo capturar la pantalla pero me da error en el FileOutputStream
no crea el archivo
Revise algunos post de StackOverflow como el siguiente [Error con el FileOutputStream](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98219/error-con-el-fileoutputstream) pero aun asi no puedo solucionarlo
El codigo es el siguiente
les agradeceria mucho si me ayudaran

```
 try {


            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +"imagen.jpg";




            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File nuevo = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream Salida = new FileOutputStream(nuevo);

            int quality = 100;

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, Salida);

            Salida.flush();
            Salida.close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HECHO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        } catch (Throwable e) {
                   Toast mal= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Que mal rollo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   mal.show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Exactamente, ¿qué error te da (muestra la parte relevante del stacktrace)? Y... ¿por qué estás abriendo dos *FileOutputStream* al mismo fichero a la vez? ¿O ha sido un error al copiar el código (tienes un botón de "editar" para corregir la pregunta)?

Comment: Gracias por responder fue un error El problema es precisamente que  declaro una variable  `FileOutputStream Salida = new FileOutputStream(nuevo);` pero no crea el archivo necesito saber donde esta el error

Comment: Yo la verdad no sé mucho de android studio, pero te recomiendo que después de Salida.flush(); Salida.close();

Comment: gracias por tu observacion