# Error al guardar imagen en almacenamiento externo

Tags: android

La idea de la aplicación, es que quiero tomar una foto y guardarla con cierto nombre en una ubicación especifica, hasta el momento, tengo: He tomado la foto, y la pongo en un `imageview`, ahora, voy a guardar la imagen. Pero cuando lo guardo, todo el código se va directamente a la parte de: "Error during image saving".

Los permisos que le otorgue a la app son:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Espero si me pueden ayudar, o brindar otro codigo.

Aca esta todo el codigo:

```
package com.agustincanoalvarez.myapplication3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    Button btnCaptura,btnGuardar;

    ImageView imageView;

    int contador=0;

    Bitmap imageBitmap;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();

        btnCaptura.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PictureIntent();
            }
        });

        btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Guardar();
            }
        });

    }

    private void init()
    {
        imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgv);
        btnCaptura =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCap);
        btnGuardar =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);

    }
    private void PictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

    private void Guardar()
    {
        contador=contador+1;

        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();



        File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


        File file = new File (sdCardDirectory,"ensayo"+String.valueOf(contador)+".png");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ensayo"+String.valueOf(contador)+".png",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        boolean success = false;

        // Encode the file as a PNG image.
        FileOutputStream outStream;
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            success = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: recuerda si lo pruebas con Android M pa delante debes otorgar los permisos en runtime, y en Android N asignar un content provaider, si puedes especificar más.

Comment: Si desarrollas en Android es importante agregues que mensaje se muestra en el LogCat, por favor consideralo.

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente como te sugiere @WebServeis, si usas Android 6.0 o posterior tienes que requerir los permisos manualmente:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android)

---

Después de esto tienes un problema, ya que estas creando un archivo en la memoria externa pero en la raíz del almacenamiento externo:

```
File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File (sdCardDirectory,"ensayo"+String.valueOf(contador)+".png");
```

Se crearía más o menos en esta ruta (varía dependiendo del OS):

```
/storage/emulated/0/ensayo12345.png
```

**Lo cual te provocaría un error, ya que no puedes escribir a este nivel.**

**En realidad debes agregarlo dentro `/Android`**, yo acostumbro agregar los archivos dentro del path:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<paquete de aplicación>/
```

que realizo de esta forma:

```
 File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File file = new File (sdCardDirectory + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName(),"ensayo"+String.valueOf(contador)+".png");
```

o simplemente puedes agregarlo dentro de `/Android/data`:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/
```

por ejemplo:

```
 File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File file = new File (sdCardDirectory + "/Android/data/","ensayo"+String.valueOf(contador)+".png");
```