# ¿Por que no me permite enviar datos de mi propia aplicación desde la carpeta de instalación?

Tags: java, android

Saludo, intento enviar un archivo almacenado en mi carpeta SDCARD, pero al ejecutar mi código me dice ningún programa puede hacer esto. Por favor alguien podría indicar y si es posible corregidme para solucionar mi problema. Gracias. El código mostrado es del entorno de android studio.

```
package com.leo.enviar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.File;

import java.io.File;

public class Main6Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String xlsname="archivo32.xls";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6);


        String[] mailto = {"ing.eo@hotmail.com"};
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),xlsname ));
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Calc PDF Report");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hi PDF is attached in this mail. ");
        emailIntent.setType("application/excel");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));
    }
}
```

---

**DESDE EL EMULADOR:**

He usado un código que crea un archivo en la siguiente ruta:

> /data/data/com.el.export/files/micarpeta

entonces tendría almacenado el siguiente archivo así:

> /data/data/com.el.export/files/micarpeta/miarchivocreado.xls

Lo anterior lo hice con la función: `getFilesDir()`

Hasta aquí no tengo problemas. Sin embargo ahora vienen:
El siguiente código acceso a mi carpeta "micarpeta" para que adjunte mi archivo "miarchivocreado.xls" pero no me lo adjunta. Ése es mi problema. El código modificado es el siguiente:

```
package com.leo.export;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;

public class Main9Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String xlsname="miarchivocreado.xls";
    String TAG="centinela";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main9);

        String[] mailto = {"elgermanolargo@gmail.com"};
        //----------------------
       // Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),xlsname ));
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File( getFilesDir().toString()+"/"+"miCarpeta/",xlsname ));


//----------------
        Log.i(TAG, "PATH:" + getFilesDir().toString()+"/"+"miCarpeta/");
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Calc PDF Report");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hi PDF is attached in this mail. ");
        emailIntent.setType("application/excel");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));
    }
}
```

¿Cuál es el motivo de que no me adjunte los datos de mi propia aplicación? es decir no estoy accediendo a datos de otra aplicación para que se considere algo malo, es que necesito descargar datos en formato excel desde mi aplicativo.

Comment: Que valor tiene la variable `uri` cuando intentas enviar el archivo?

Comment: ¿Tienes permiso de acceso al almacenamiento externo en el Manifest?

Comment: Si usas android 6.0 o mayor debes pedir el pemiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE manualmente, no es suficiente con declararlo en el manifest.xml. Si tienes permisos y no funciona solo asegura la ruta sea la correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
String SD_CARD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
new File(SD_CARD_PATH + "/" + xlsname);
```

Comment: con getAbsolutePath que usa el usuario se obtiene "/" al final.

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, en mi log ninguna de las dos funciones retorna "/" al final. "/storage/emulated/0". Seria bueno que agregara un volcado para revisar la ruta.

Comment: ahhhhh es que lo estas imprimiendo directamente, en este caso el OP usa (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), fileName ) , con esto no necesita agregar un "/" al final, el método File() lo crea sin problema. Como lo tienes tu es también correcto y si se debe agregar "/" para concatenar con el nombre de archivo!.

Answer (score 0):

**Como enviar un archivo excel :**

Primeramente es importante mencionar que si usas sistema operativo Android 6.0 o posterior, debes requerir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` manualmente, no es suficiente definirlo dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, aquí un ejemplo de como realizarlo:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

esto puede ser una causa de tu problema.

Si tienes definido el permiso mencionado anteriormente, **debes revisar que la ruta donde se contiene el archivo sea correcta, en este caso el archivo se encuentra en la ruta correcta del almacenamiento externo**, para esto puedes imprimir la ruta:

```
Log.i(TAG, "PATH: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```

También es importante revisar que el archivo exista!, en el caso de usar como ruta `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` , tu archivo se debe encontrar dentro de:

```
/storage/emulated/0/archivo32.xls
```

---

Este sería el código de un ejemplo de como enviar un archivo .xls usando [createChooser()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
String fileName ="tests-example.xls";
String MIME_TYPE = "application/excel";

        Log.i(TAG, "PATH: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/Android/data/");

        String[] mailto = {"correo@gmail.com"};

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/Android/data/", fileName ));
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Mi reporte");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Envio mi archivo excel. ");
        emailIntent.setType(MIME_TYPE);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Selecciona como deseas enviar el archivo:"));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias a sus comentarios lo que hice fue configurar en mi cell una cuenta de google (gmail) y enviiarme a un correo gmail también. Luego el mismo código que plantee corrió de las mil maravillas

Comment: 0_o bueno eso es obvio, si deseas enviar por email un archivo debes tener un cliente funcionando.

Comment: es que yo tenía configurado un correo de hotmail no del ....

Comment: Android requiere una cuenta configurada, esto principalmente para habilitar la playstore y poder instalar aplicaciones.

Comment: NADIE SABE??????

Comment: A que te refieres? No habías solucionado este problema?

Comment: Es que leí por ahí que en esta comunidad si quieres hacer preguntas del mismo tema que preguntastes tienes que modificar la pregunta. Y como ve han corregido las preguntas no he querido tener problemas. Por eso que agregé mas preguntas. Pucha AVISO QUE VOYA CREAR OTRA PREGUNTA DEL MISMO TEMA Y ESPERO NO ME LLAMEN LA ATENCION