# ¿Cómo puedo abrir un archivo PDF usando Intent en Android Nougat?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Agradeceré su ayuda para poder hacer que mi código pueda abrir un archivo PDF en un Intent, el código que he venido usando para hacerlo es:

```
String pathFile =
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +
    FileUtils.PATH_SEPARATOR + "myFolder" +
    FileUtils.PATH_SEPARATOR + "myFile.pdf";
File pdfFile = new File( pathFile );
if ( pdfFile.exists() ) {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( new File( pathFile ) );
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

Pero entiendo que ahora (desde la versión Android-N) los privilegios se manejan de manera distinta y por eso espero que me puedan ayudar indicándome cuáles son los cambios que debo hacer para que se pueda abrir un archivo PDF en un Intent.

PD: En mi AndroidManifest.xml tengo solicitado permiso para todo el STORAGE:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: ¿Tiene instalado algún lector de pdf?

Comment: La nuevas versiones de Android (N+) necesitan manejar FileProvider para tener acceso a los archivos por motivos de seguridad; la respuesta exacta a mi problema la encontré en: http://android.2317887.n4.nabble.com/FileProvider-td394588.html
Espero que a alguien le sirva tanto como a mi.

Comment: en versiones de sistema operativo iguales o superiores a Android N debes usar Uri.parse() en lugar de Uri.fromFile()

Answer (score 1):

Verifica la ruta al archivo y añade una exception si no lo puede abrir.

```
if(file.exists()) {
            Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ActivityNotFound" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El archivo no existe." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

yo hice este método

Primero tienes que consultar la version del SO

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
     if (checkPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")) {

     }else{
       requestPermissions("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
     }
}else{
//TODO: Como es menor a la versión N puedes abrir el archivo
}
```

Con este método verifico si ha aceptado, pasándole como String el permiso

```
private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
        int res = this.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
        return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

Con este método realizo la solicitud del Permiso, puedes pasarle varios permisos al mismo tiempo

```
private void requestPermissions(String... permissions) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 0);
}
```

Lo que te faltaría hacer es consultar en @OnActivityResult

Comment: HOla Marcos... no me funciona ya que obtengo el mismo error: 
.......archivo.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

Comment: Yo uso esta librería para abrir archivos PDF, los descargo y los leo 
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Answer (score 1):

A partir de Android 6.0 el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` debe ser pedido de manera manual, no es suficiente con declararlo en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, para esto aquí se tiene como obtenerlos:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

En cuanto al error que estas teniendo, debes recordar que **en versiones de sistema operativo iguales o superiores a Android N debes usar `Uri.parse()` en lugar de `Uri.fromFile()`** :

```
    Uri uri;
    //Validación de acuerdo al OS.            
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
           uri = Uri.parse(filepath);
    } else{
           uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
    }
```

**Si no realizas esta validación, en Android N obtendrías este error: [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html):**