# No puedo ver archivos creados desde App android 6.0 en explorador de archivo windows

Tags: android-studio

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/Inventario");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        if (folder.mkdirs()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Carpeta Creada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

la aplicación genera la carpeta y es visible desde el explorador del 'dispositivo', pero cuando intento acceder desde el computador no me muestra la carpeta. solo es visible luego de reiniciar el 'dispositivo'.
la versión de android es 6.0

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar [tour]

Comment: Estuve probando con diferente versiones lo mismo que estás diciendo y solo me funcionó con las versiones de la 5.1 para abajo , se ve que las versiones más adelantadas tienen protegido esos archivos

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @fito120, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, es muy importante leer [ask] , es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado e investigado, saludos!

Comment: @IgnacioBelmonte
de hecho la aplicación fue creada para un dispositivo con android 5.1 y funcionaba bien. ahora al instalar en un android 6.0 no funciona y no pasa por un tema de permisos (ya los asigné)  porque la app crea la carpeta. pero cuando trato de acceder desde windows no me muestra la carpeta creada

Answer (score -1):

Si tienes archivos o carpetas creadas en el directorio de almacenamiento externo, estos se pueden visualizar sin problema mediante algun explorador de archivos o el mismo `File Explorer` de `Android Studio`.

**Aquí el problema es que aunque puedas visualizar los archivos mediante el [explorador de archivos (File Explorer)](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html?hl=es-419), programaticamente no puedes realizar la lectura de archivos o directorios si no defines el permiso de [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)**, al definir este permiso esta implícito el permiso de `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Para versiones de sistema operativo Android anteriores a 6.0, es suficiente definir el permiso dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Para versiones posteriores a Android 6.0 es importante además requerir los permisos manualmente.

En esta pregunta puedes ver un método para requerir el permiso:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android)

---

Importante comentar que en algunas versiones de sistema operativo android no existe el directorio "Documents" al que hace relación `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS`, por lo tanto primeramente se tiene que crear.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tengo agregado el permiso y la app crea la carpeta en el directorio de android. el problema está al acceder desde el explorador de windows. solo funciona cuando reinicio el dispositivo android.

Comment: Estas requiriendo el permiso manualmente también? @fito120

Comment: claro... asigno el permiso en AndroidManifest y ademas lo solicito por programación como lo requiere android 6.0... como te comenté la carpeta se crea en la raiz de android pero me da la impresión que falta algo para que quede publica.

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: @fito120 veo que usas DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS!!! es que no esta creado, crea primero el directorio : File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");