# Permiso denegado al leer un archivo

Tags: android

Que tal comunidad buen día. Soy nuevo en el grupo y necesito de su ayuda.

Tengo un codigo en java para leer un archivo de texto lina por lenea y almacenarlo en una matriz para retornar el valor de la matriz.

el codigo lo compilo en netbeans y me retorna el valor de forma correcta. al adaptar este mismo codigo en Android studio, me retorna un error de permisos.

Los permisos de lectura de la SD se los otorgo en el archivo archivo Manifest y me presenta el siguiete error (tomado del Logcat):

> I/System.out: /storage/emulated/0/Download/script.txt W/System.err:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/script.txt
>   (Permission denied) W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200) W/System.err:
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:150)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:103) W/System.err:
>   at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58) W/System.err:     at
>   com.lexuntu.cda.launcherbox.LeerArchivo.LeerArchivo(LeerArchivo.java:18)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.lexuntu.cda.launcherbox.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:34)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
>   W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown
>   Source:0) W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5305120: ver 2 0 (tinfo
>   0xe5303340)

Anexo fragmento de codigo, espero les sirva y me puedan apoyar a resolver este inconveniente.

```
//CLASE LeerArchivo
public class LeerArchivo {

    public static String [] LeerArchivo(String Archivo) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(Archivo);
        FileReader Fr = new FileReader(Archivo);
        BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(Fr);

       String matriz[]=new String [39];

        int cont=0;
        try {
            String lines = "";
            while( ( lines = Br.readLine()) != null) {
                matriz[cont]=lines;
                cont++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No se encontro el Archivo "+file.getName());
        }
        Fr.close();
        Br.close();
        return matriz;
    }
}

///fragmento de MainActivity


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {   //Cancelado por el usuario
        }
        if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == VALOR_RETORNO)) {//Procesar el resultado
            Uri uri = data.getData();//getData(); //obtener el uri content
            arch = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(uri)).getLastPathSegment().substring(4);
            System.out.println(arch);
            try {
                String[] Times = new String[39];
                Times = LeerArchivo.LeerArchivo(arch);
                //llenarTimes(arch);
              for(int i=0;i<=39;i++){
                  System.out.println(Times[i]);
              }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No tienes permisos para leer en el directorio de almacenamiento externo:

> /storage/emulated/0/Download/script.txt (Permission denied)

esto puede ser debido a que no has definido el permiso

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Recuerda si usas sistema operativo Andriod 6.0 o mayor debes requerir permisos manualmente:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

Comment: "Los permisos de lectura de la SD se los otorgo en el archivo archivo Manifest y me presenta el siguiete error (tomado del Logcat):"

Comment: @lexuntu que sistema operativo usa tu dispositivo, si es mayor a 6.0 este lo debes requerir manualmente.