# Descarga de archivos webview android

Tags: android, fpdf, webview, descarga

Qué tal, Tengo una duda con respecto a la descarga de archivos desde un web view en android utilizando el DownloadManager.
Tengo este código:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setMimeType(mimetype);
                String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                        DownloadManager .Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                                | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);

                request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
                request.setDescription("Descargando Archivo...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Funciona correctamente al descargar archivos de los cuáles cuento con una URL, o sea el archivo ya existe, sin embargo, si el archivo es generado  al momento de hacer la petición (por ejemplo con la librería TCPDF o con reporting service) me arroja un error en la descarga.

Comment: Es importante especificar al preguntar cual es el error,¿que se muestra en el LogCat?, ¿Que MIME TYPE estas definiendo? ¿Que defines como contentDisposition ?saludos.

Comment: El logcat no arroja ningún error, simplemente el archivo al quererlo abrir me marca error

Comment: El mismo DownloadManager  genera su información de debug en el LogCat, recuerda que puedes imprimir también información como la ruta del archivo donde sera descargado o si tienes o no permisos definidos, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Para usar la clase `DownloadManager` es necesario contemplar tener definidos los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

pero además debes requerir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` manualmente, revisa :

[Permiso denegado al leer un archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167191/permiso-denegado-al-leer-un-archivo/167198#167198)

Ahora es importante que la url del archivo sea válida, y que el MIME TYPE definido para el archivo .pdf sea definido como `"application/pdf"`

```
  request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
```

Ahora el directorio y el nombre del archivo deben ser definidos dentro del método `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` pero pudieras tener problema al definir el nombre ya que estas usando `URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype)`, asegura que este método genere un nombre de archivo (incluyendo extensión) con el cual el archivo descargado será guardado, por ejemplo :

```
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,  "pdf_sample.pdf");
```

incluso podrías imprimir la ruta donde el archivo será guardad:

```
    Log.i(TAG, "The file will be downloaded as : " + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "pdf_sample.pdf");
```

recuerda que el archivo será guardado dentro del directorio `/dowloads` ya que definiste `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería el código:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setMimeType(mimetype);
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
//request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
        DownloadManager .Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);

request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
request.setTitle("PDF File");
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,  "pdf_sample.pdf");
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comparto un ejemplo completo:

**[Android DownloadManager](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-DownloadManager)**

Comment: El problema es que no hay una "url del archivo". sino que el archivo es generado al momento, (por ejemplo con la librería TCPDF o con reporting service)

Comment: Entonces como usas : DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url)); ? se necesita una url para descargar el archivo.

Comment: mediante el mismo webView accedo a otros sitios donde el archivo a descargar ya cuenta con una ruta definida(O sea, el archivo ya existe y en las cuáles se descarga sin problemas), pero hay otras donde el archivo es generado dinámicamente, son justamente esas las que me es imposible descargar el archivo.

Comment: Ok DownloadManager solo se usa para descargar un archivo a partir de una url, en el caso de la url de un pdf la puede descargar sin problema, si tienes otra condición en la cual el archivo se genera dinamicamente considera agregar como se genera o agrega otra pregunta donde agregues esta información.

Comment: La pregunta original lo especifica

Comment: agrega el código de como realiza la petición y como obtienes el archivo, obtienes un inputStream?