# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen que se encuentra en una carpeta diferente en el dispositivo Android?

Tags: android, imagen, diseño, rutas

Hola estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen en un ImageView pero el problema es que la ruta la tengo guardada de la siguiente manera:

```
/storage/emulated/0/AsiatechApp/images/2285Success.jpg
```

Pero lo que pide el ImageView es un Uri, mi pregunta es existe una manera de mostrarla con la ruta que tengo, la ruta es traída directamente de una BD.

Ya intenté con la conversión Uri.Parse pero sigue sin reconocerla me arroja como resultado lo siguiente:

```
/storage/emulated/0/AsiatechApp/images/2285Success.jpg
```

Que es lo mismo.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda

El código donde doy la ruta de la imagen es el siguiente.

```
Uri urii= (Uri.parse(ma.getRutaimg()));
vh.imagen.setImageURI(urii);
```

Comment: Puedes poner el código de como estas tratando de enviar la imagen al ImageView.

Comment: ¿Si tienes agregados los permisos en el Manifest para poder leer la memoria externa?

Comment: hola @Alfredo esa imagen previamente la guardaste en tu dispositivo o solo estas obteniendo la ruta desde la base de datos?

Comment: @Jorgesys si la imagen se encuentra físicamente en el directorio la copie previamente

Comment: @Serna mi problema no es de permisos es que como tal no se como indicar la ruta que espera un uri pero tengo la ruta absoluta

Comment: @Alfredo si aseguras que el archivo existe en : /storage/emulated/0/AsiatechApp/images/2285Success.jpg entonces el problema es relacionado a permisos, recuerda que para dispositivos Android con sistema operativo 6.0 o posterior la petición del permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, debe ser manual.

Comment: @Jorgesys el permiso si lo tengo ese no es el problema, el problema es que no muestra la imagen con las rutas mostradas

Comment: Usa glide es lo mejorcito para abrir imagenes tanto del disko como del internet.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tratas de realizar es correcto:

```
Uri myUri = (Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/AsiatechApp/images/2285Success.jpg"));
imageView.setImageURI(myUri);
```

pero si la tratas de cargar mediante [**setImageURI()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) y no funciona pueden ser 2 razones:

1) la imagen en realidad NO existe en la ruta:

```
/storage/emulated/0/AsiatechApp/images/2285Success.jpg
```

2) debes asegurar tener definido el permiso :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

y para dispositivos con Android 6.0 o mayor la petición del permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` debe ser manual, revisa esta respuesta:

**[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)**