# Error al Copiar File de directorio downloads a otro, open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) en api level 19

Tags: android, android-studio, fileupload

Buen día.Tengo el siguiente problema en ANDROID STUDIO, tengo una aplicación en el que el usuario elige un Archivo pdf o word, obtiene la ruta del path y si el usuario decide subir  el file al servidor, la aplicacion copia el file seleccionado y lo pega en un directorio interno creado y desde ahí recien procede a subir el file al servidor.
La aplicacion trabaja desde un api minimo de 18 a 27.he probado en un dispositivo de api 21 Android 5.0.2 y no hay problemas; cuando he probado con un dispositvo de api level 19 android 4.4.2 de la carpeta downloads,surge el siguiente problema en el Logcat:

```
11-15 13:53:27.303 4363-4363/? E/CrearCarpteaAlIn: Error: No se creo el directorio privado
11-15 13:53:27.303 4363-4363/? E/Error: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-15 13:53:27.303 4363-4363/? W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-15 13:53:27.313 4363-4363/? W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:972)
    at com.example.usuario.prueba.SubirArchivosPDFWORD.onClick(SubirArchivosPDFWORD.java:161)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4578)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18654)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
11-15 13:53:27.323 4363-4363/? W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:965)
    ... 12 more
```

si bien dice Error de Permisos tengo adjutando los permisos en el manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

He buscado el problema en internet y no encuentro la solucion al problema, me parece que es porque no obtiene correctamente el path cuando lo obtiene de downlodas ya que lo que obtiene es

```
   E/PATH: /data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/ordcom64-doc2018-06-15.pdf
```

En cambio en el Path en otra version de android es

```
     E/PATH: /storge/emulated/0/Download/solucione.pdf
```

Este es mi manifest completo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DescargarArchivosPDF">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SubirImagenes">


    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Galeria">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SubirArchivosPDFWORD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Esta es mi actividad:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

//FUNCIONA, SUBE ARCHIVOS DE INTERNO Y EXTERNO
public class SubirArchivosPDFWORD extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button BtnExaminar_Archivos, BtnSubir_Archivos;
    private TextView TxVwNombre;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 124;
    private boolean PERM_WRITE = false;
    private String PATHIREAL, PATHREAL = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subir_archivos_pdf_word);
    BtnExaminar_Archivos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnExaminar_Archivos);
    BtnSubir_Archivos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnSubir_Archivos);
    TxVwNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxVwNombre);
    BtnExaminar_Archivos.setOnClickListener(this);
    BtnSubir_Archivos.setOnClickListener(this);
    SolicitarPermiso();
}

void SolicitarPermiso() {
    ///Pregunta los Permisos
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //PERMISO DENEGADO
        //HAY RESPUESTA
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "HAY RPA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //PERMISO DENEGADO
            if (getPackageManager().PERMISSION_DENIED == -1) {
                //PERMISO DENEGADO ANTERIORMENTE
                Toast.makeText(this, "DENEGADO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ///PIDE PERMISO
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            } else {///PERMISO ACEPTADO
                PERM_WRITE = true;
            }
        } else {
            ///NO HAY RESPUESTA
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "NOHAY RPA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PERM_WRITE = false;
        }
    } else {//PERMISO ACEPTADO
        PERM_WRITE = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Aceptado Write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "HAY RPTA READ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Aceptado Read", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    //LLega Sirve para procesar la respuesta del Permiso
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "SI HAY PERMISO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                PERM_WRITE = true;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "NO HAY PERMISO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                PERM_WRITE = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.BtnExaminar_Archivos:
            SolicitarPermiso();
            if (PERM_WRITE) {
                String[] mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("application/*").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
                //intent.setType("image/JPG");
                //intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                //intent.setType("image/jpg");
                //intent.setType("image/png");
                //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                Uri mImageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Seleccione un DOCUMENTO"),
                        1);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.BtnSubir_Archivos:
            try {
                File interno = new File(crearCarpetaAlmInterno() + "/" + new File(PATHREAL).getName());
                File temp = new File(PATHREAL);
                temp.createNewFile();
                copyFile(temp, interno);
                new UploadFile(interno.getAbsolutePath()).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //new UploadFile(PATHREAL).execute();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri selectedImage;
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        String name = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();
        PATHIREAL = data.getData().getPath();
        try {
            PATHREAL = getFilePath(this, data.getData());
            TxVwNombre.setText("name=" + name + " PATH=" + PATHREAL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("PATH", PATHREAL);
    }

}

public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                    .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());

}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/***crear Directorio en la memoria interna     */

public File crearCarpetaAlmInterno() {
    String nombreDirectorio = "TCompra";
    //Crear directorio en la memoria interna.
    File directorioInterno = new File(getFilesDir(), nombreDirectorio);
    //Muestro un mensaje en el logcat si no se creo la carpeta por algun motivo
    if (!directorioInterno.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("CrearCarpteaAlIn", "Error: No se creo el directorio privado");
    }

    if (directorioInterno.exists() && directorioInterno.isDirectory()) {//SI EXISTE
        Toast.makeText(this, "DIRECTORIO EXISTE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {//NO EXISTE
        Toast.makeText(this, "DIRECTORIO NO EXISTE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    return directorioInterno;
}

public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel origen = null;
    FileChannel destino = null;
    try {
        origen = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destino = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();

        long count = 0;
        long size = origen.size();
        while ((count += destino.transferFrom(origen, count, size - count)) < size) ;
    } finally {
        if (origen != null) {
            origen.close();
        }
        if (destino != null) {
            //destFile.mkdirs();
            destino.close();
        }
    }
}


private class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String PATREAL = null;

    public UploadFile(String PATREAL) {
        this.PATREAL = PATREAL;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        File f = new File(this.PATREAL);


        //String content_type = getMimeType(this.PATREAL);
        String content_type = getMimeType2(PATREAL);
        Log.i("content_type ", content_type);
        String file_path = PATREAL;
        Log.d("File ", file_path);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type), f);
        RequestBody request_body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("type", content_type)
                .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file", file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), file_body)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://www.nube.com/Surbir.php")
                .post(request_body)
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                //Toast.makeText(SubirImagenes.this, "Archivo no subido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                throw new IOException("Error : " + response);

            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }


        return null;
    }
}

private String getMimeType(String path) {

    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
    if (extension != null) {
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.toLowerCase());
    }
    return type;


}

public static String getMimeType2(String url) {
    String extension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("."));
    String mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(extension);
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(mimeTypeMap);
    return mimeType;
}

}
```

Gracias por su Tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar este tipo de problema y obtener el directorio de descargas `/Download` se sugiere usar

[Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) y definir el tipo de directorio a retornar que en este caso sería [Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

```
String dirDownloads = 
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
```

de esta forma obtendrás la ruta definida en cualquier dispositivo.

---

Recuerda que para dispositivos con sistema operativo mayor a 6.0 debes requerir los permisos

[Petición permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE en android 6.0 o superior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24934/95)

Comment: Gracias por tu Respuesta, encontre el error es tonto, pero me ha complicado más de un día de trabajo.En la parte de abajo explico el error a detalle. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el Error varias veces, Debugueando otras veces más, me di con la sorpresa que el dispositivo LG-D331 con version de Android 4.4.2. Al abrir el explorador de archivos, enviaba por defecto a DESCARGAS, en el cual se listaba varias archivos, los cuales se ven en la siguiente imagen
[image: Toma de pantalla del explorador por defecto]

En el cual despues de elegir uno de los lista de mostraba el PATH DE ESTA FORMA, es con el que tenia problemas al momento de copiar a una carpeta interna.

[image: Imagen despuesde de elegir el archivo de los que se muestran en la lista anterior]

Entonces despues de tanta fustracion envie desde otro dispositivo un file por bluetooh, el cual se había almacenado en la memomria interna [download] y que en dicho directorio no se observa los archivos listados en la primera imagen.

[image: Imagen de los archivos de la carpeta Downloda]

En resumen, el error consistía en que el dispositivo no podía acceder a files que se muestarn del directorio Descargas (Ruta por defecto al abrir el explorador de archivos en la aplicacion), de los cuales dichos files al buscarlos y abrir el directorio de la memoriainterna/Download no están(no son visibles). El dispositivo muestra archivos que no son visibles, aparentemmente que estan almacenados en cache, que son inaccesibles al buscarlos por nombre.
Entonces la aplicacion al querer copiar el path obtenido no lo puede hacer y muestra la excepcion **EACCES (Permission denied).**

**GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA**, fue mi primer post