# Como crear un directorio y grabar un archivo txt en la memoria externa SD

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una app en la cual estoy intentando crear el directorio "Download/Datax" y grabar archivos txt en la memoria externa SD y estoy usando este código:

```
File directorioExt = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS ), "/Download/Datax/" );
if (!directorioExt.exists()) {
   File directoriox = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/Datax/" );
   directoriox.mkdirs();
   }
```

Pero no se logra crear el directorio en la memoria externa.
también he colocado en el manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Alguien me puede decir como lograr esto?

Comment: Tu código es correcto para crear el directorio, tu dispositivo tiene Android 6.0 o posterior, debes requerir el permiso manualmente. Recuerda que es importante revisar el LogCat ahí me mostrará información detallada sobre el problema, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad tu código es correcto:

```
File directorioExt = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS ), "/Download/Datax/" );
if (!directorioExt.exists()) {
   File directoriox = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/Datax/" );
   directoriox.mkdirs();
}
```

Una de las causas por las cuales no podrías crear el directorio especificado es el no tener el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, para dispositivos con sistema operativo Android 6.0 no es suficiente definirlo en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` , debes requerirlo manualmente:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Revisa esta respuesta:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)