# java.io.FileNotFoundException open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) pero sí existe el archivo Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

soy nuevo en programación en Android y me tope con este problema, intento abrir un archivo de texto para leerlo pero no lo consigo, me marca el error  que muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Error al ejecutar la app]

Sin embargo al explorar se puede apreciar que sí se encuentra el archivo:

[image: Archivos]

Mi código XML es el siguiente:

> 

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Y mi codigo Java:

> 

```
package com.example.log_v_02;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
//import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String CHANNEL_ID = "NOTIFICACION";
    private final static int NOTIFICACION_ID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OnCreate() Inicio",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                try {
                    Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
                    m.invoke(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OnResume() Inicio",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        if ( isExternalStorageWritable() ) {


            File appDirectory = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ZeroLogProyect" );
            File logDirectory = new File( appDirectory + "/log" );
            File logFile = new File( logDirectory, "logcat" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt" );


            if ( !appDirectory.exists() ) {

                appDirectory.mkdir();

            }


            if ( !logDirectory.exists() ) {

                logDirectory.mkdir();

            }


            try {
                //Depura logs
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -c");

                //Crea archivo de logs
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -v brief -f " + logFile + " *:W" );

                //Carga archivo de logs
                FileInputStream archivo_entrada = null;
                archivo_entrada = new FileInputStream(logFile);
                InputStreamReader formato_lectura = new InputStreamReader(archivo_entrada);
                BufferedReader lector = new BufferedReader(formato_lectura);


                String linea_archivo;
                //expresion regular
                String patron = ".*main.*";

                //Empieza lectura de archivo logs
                  while((linea_archivo=lector.readLine()) != null){
                      Boolean matches = Pattern.matches(patron,linea_archivo);

                      if(matches){

                          //Saca notificacion
                          createNotification();
                      }

                }
                lector.close();


            } catch ( IOException e ) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        } else if ( isExternalStorageReadable() ) {

            // solo lectura

        } else {

            // sin acceso, hay un error

        }

    }

    //Termina programa


    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ) {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }




    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals( state ) ) {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }


    private void createNotification(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning_black_24dp);
        builder.setContentTitle("Proyecto ");
        builder.setContentText("ZeroLog ha detectado un proceso.");
        builder.setColor(Color.RED);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        builder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000});
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICACION_ID, builder.build());
    }



}
```

Al parecer en el explorador de archivos de Android aparece la ruta como /storage/emulated/legacy/ mientras que en el momento que expulsa el error se puede apreciar que tiene como dirección: /storage/emulated/0/

Apreciería mucho su ayuda, gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Aunque el mensaje puede indicar que no existe el archivo:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory) pero sí existe el archivo Android Studio

Se tienen 2 causas que provocan este problema que son:

- El archivo no existe.
- No se tienen permisos para leer y escribir, recuerda que para Android 6.0 o mayor la petición de permisos de realizarse de forma manual.

En este caso te sugiero que ademas de definir los permisos en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` realices la petición manual:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
     int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Revisa esta pregunta :

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android)

Answer (score 0):

¿Tienes el mismo problema?
lo solucione agregando lo siguiente en mi AndroidManifest.xml

<application
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/371989)