# Compartir archivo mp3 de la carpeta Raw

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero compartir un audio desde la carpeta Raw en Android pero no me reconoce el formato mp3 de los audios.

Como verán tengo un método llamado "compartir" que se ejecuta luego de mantener presionado un botón. Este método es para compartir un audio formato mp3 a las redes sociales pero no puedo lograr que me detecte el formato .mp3

```
   //Mi boton que al mantener pulsado por un periodo va llamar al metodo compartir

    buttonRep25= (Button)findViewById(button25);
    buttonRep25.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    //llamada al metodo donde le damos los valores (int a1 ,String a2)

        compartir(R.raw.futuru_por_pasado,"futuru_por_pasado.mp3");
        return false;

    }

});



 //Metodo Compartir
public void compartir (int a1 ,String a2)
{
try {

// Abrimos el recurso y lo metemos en un bufer

    InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(a1);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[ins.available()];
    ins.read(buffer);
    ins.close();

  // Grabamos el bufer en un fichero
    String filename = getExternalCacheDir().toString() + a2;
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    fos.write(buffer);
    fos.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

File open = new File(getExternalCacheDir().toString() + a2);

final Intent comparte = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
comparte.setType("audio");
comparte.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(open));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(comparte,"Enviar a..."));




    }
```

Comment: Hola Mattias, suponiendo que tienes permisos y el archivo se copio sin problemas a el directorio de almacenamiento externo, me parece que el problema es el tipo que defines, debe ser: comparte.setType("audio/*");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si recibes un mensaje que indica que no puede enviar el archivo puede ser debido a 2 causas:

- Debes asegurar definir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` en tu AndroidManifest.xml y requerirlo manualmente para dispositivos con OS 6.0.
- El archivo que tratas de enviar debe existir en la ruta definida y mostraría un mensaje que indica que ese "formato" no puede ser usado.
- **El tipo debe ser definido como : comparte.setType("audio/*"); de otra forma no podrás compartir el archivo.**

---

**Compartir archivo .mp3 almacenado en la carpeta /raw.**

En este caso cuando tratamos de enviar algún recurso mediante e-mail o mensajería, puedes como opción realizar una copia al directorio de almacenamiento externo para poder anexarlo sin problemas, te sugiero usar este método:

[Copiar archivo desde RAW a el directorio de almacenamiento externo.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46244121/250260)

```
private void copyFiletoExternalStorage(int resourceId, String pathSDCard){
    try{
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Obviamente [requieres de permisos de escritura/lectura (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

y puedes realizar el envió mediante un Intent.createChooser() donde puedes seleccionar "Whatsapp" para compartir archivo .mp3 de la carpeta `/raw`:

```
   String fileName = "my_sound.mp3";
    copyFiletoExternalStorage(R.raw.mysound, fileName);

    String outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + File.separator +  fileName;

    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        uri = Uri.parse(outputFile);
    } else{
        uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(outputFile));
    }


    Intent share = new Intent();
    share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/*");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Compartir audio .mp3"));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]