# Android Studio Error open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estuve sigueindo esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277311/compartir-archivo-mp3-de-la-carpeta-raw) para compartir un archivo de audio .mp3 al presionar un boton desde un Adapter en Android Studio, el hecho es que al hacerlo me envia el sigueinte error `Error open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)` y ademas en la aplicación me muestra un toast que dice `Este formato de archivo no es compatible`, adjunto mi código ya navegue por otras preguntas y no logro dar con la solucion.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Adapter.java**

```
            compartir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {

                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        //no anda
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            String fileName = "hola.mp3";
                            copyFiletoExternalStorage(R.raw.hola, fileName);

                            String outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + File.separator + fileName;

                            Uri uri;
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                uri = Uri.parse(outputFile);
                            } else {
                                uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(outputFile));
                            }


                            Intent share = new Intent();
                            share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            share.setType("audio/*");
                            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

                            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Compartir audio .mp3"));
                        }

                    }
                }
            });




private void copyFiletoExternalStorage(int resourceId, String pathSDCard) {
            try {
                InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
                FileOutputStream out = null;
                out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                int read = 0;
                try {
                    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buff, 0, read);
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }


        }
```

Comment: como quieres compartir las cosas con android sharesheet?? si es asi te puedo ayudar

Comment: Exacto, pero quiero compartir un .mp3 y lo que comento en la pregunta es lo que no me esta funcionando

Comment: Si tu dispositivo es >= android 6, comprueba en ajustes de tu app los permisos de lectura están activados, si no es así actívalos y verifica si se reproduce el error.  Lo ideal es pedir permisos en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: @ManuelMato Los permisos los pido, pero al parecer no surgen efecto. Alguna idea?

Comment: Pues no entiendo que al pedirlos en tiempo de ejecución no salgan... De todas formas comprobaste en ajustes que están activados? Si es así y no funcionan, prueba con otro móvil

Comment: @ManuelMato Los permisos los pido asi al iniciar la app:
`Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Pero todavía no sé si has comprobado en ajustes -> aplicaciones y notificaciones -> selecciona tu app -> permisos y ahí deben aparecer los permisos y si están concedidos o no, verifica que la escritura está concedida.  Si no lo está, actívalos manualmente y prueba la aplicación y coméntanos cómo ha ido ;)

Comment: @ManuelMato Por lo que veo en Apps>Mi App>Permisos, solo aparece el de Almacenamiento y el de Cambiar los ajustes del sistema, sera por eso que falla?

Comment: y dentro de Almacenamiento aparece activada la opción de Permitir o Denegar?

Comment: @ManuelMato Permitido. Para mi el problema es que no esta escribiendo el archivo en la SD por lo tanto al querer leerlo no lo encuentra

Comment: pero para poder escribir hay que saber si el permiso realmente lo tiene, por eso es necesario saber si en el sistema consta como permitido o denegado.  Saber eso es clave para indagar si hay un problema con la request de los permisos en tiempo de ejecución o que realmente la lógica de guardado no es correcta, o incluso el path del fichero, así que por favor revísa cómo consta el permiso y me dices, gracias.

Comment: @ManuelMato Si, cuenta con el permiso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario escribir en la memoria externa para guardar archivos de tu aplicación, puedes utilizar el directorio caché de tu aplicación, es recomendable que no guardes archivos grandes y que los borres cada cierto tiempo, además no necesita ningún tipo de permiso especial.

El código dónde atrapas el click del adaptador quedaría así:

```
compartir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (listener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            //si anda
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                String fileName = "hola.mp3";
                File mp3File = new File(getCacheDirectory(),fileName);
                copyFileToCache(R.raw.hola,mp3File);
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "nombre.de.tu.paquete.fileprovider", mp3File);
                Intent share = new Intent();
                share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("audio/*");
                share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Compartir audio .mp3"));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Tú método de copiado a memoria externa cambió un poco, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
private void copyFileToCache(int resourceId,File file) {
    try {
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage()!=null?e.getMessage():e.toString());
    }
}
```

Y agregué un método extra que es el encargado de obtener o crear el directorio de caché de tu aplicación, además cada que es invocado borra los archivos que tienes en dicho directorio:

```
private File getCacheDirectory(){
    //get cache dir path
    File cacheDir = getCacheDir();
    //get custom folder path inside cache dir
    File customCacheFolder = new File(cacheDir, "/mp3_cache/");
    if (!customCacheFolder.exists()) {
        //create custom folder inside cache dir
        boolean wasSuccessful = customCacheFolder.mkdirs();
        if (!wasSuccessful) {
            Log.e(TAG, "An error ocurred while creating cache dir");
        }
    }
    //for clearing files in cache
    File[] files = customCacheFolder.listFiles();
    if(files!=null){
        for (File file:files) {
            //delete file from custom cache folder
            boolean wasSuccessful = file.delete();
            if (!wasSuccessful) {
                Log.e(TAG, "An error ocurred while deleting file: "+file.getName()
                        +" from: "+customCacheFolder.getPath());
            }
        }
    }

    return customCacheFolder;
}
```

Además es necesario que crees el directorio **xml** dentro del directorio **res**, y dentro de xml crees el archivo

> **file_paths.xml**

con el siguiente contenido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path
        name="MP3"
        path="mp3_cache/" />
</paths>
```

Y por último agregas lo siguiente en tu AndroidManifest dentro de los tags application:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mahm.sharemp3.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Con esto puedes exitosamente compartir tu archivo a través del intent te dejo captura del ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo el repositorio del ejemplo por si gustas descargarlo.

https://github.com/limpmike/ShareMP3

Lo que se está haciendo con el código anterior es básicamente crear un directorio interno dentro del directorio que es asignado a tu aplicación, este es tuyo por ende no es necesario que se le pida algún permiso de lectura o escritura al usuario, esto último te da una ventaja dado que no existe la posibilidad de que te revoquen el permiso, a mi parecer simplifica la lógica y mejora la experiencia.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder! El programa sigue sin funcionar, ahora me tira el siguiente error `E/Constraints: /data/user/0/com.example.test/cache/mp3_cache/hola.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Como dato extra al descargar tu repositorio y probarlo me arroja el mismo error, `E/MainActivity: /data/user/0/com.mahm.sharemp3/cache/mp3_cache/hola.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Hola @TaD, una disculpa tuve un pequeño error en el código, pude replicar tu error en android 5.0, y lo corregí, en el caso de mi código se debe al borrado de archivos de la cache, cuándo se da delete a un File, se borran archivos y carpetas si están vacías en este caso se cumplía la condición y se estaba borrando la carpeta.

Comment: Actualicé el repositorio, y el código en la respuesta, específicamente tienes que cambiar la variable cacheDir por customCacheFolder al hacer el listFiles(), esto en el método getCacheDirectory(), saludos.

Comment: Funciona como esperaba, muchas gracias!