# Como puedo compartir un archivo de audio de la carpeta raw de android studio a apps como whatsapp, etc?

Tags: java, android, studio, whatsapp, telegram

He buscado como compartir un archivo de audio que se encuentra en la carpeta raw de android studio a apps externas como whatsapp, telegram, etc; He buscado en varios foros y he buscado en este mismo, encontre supuestas soluciones, pero ninguna me ha funcionado, asi que quisiera que alguien me ayude con el codigo definitivo para hacer que esto funcione, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar [ask], edita tu pregunta,esta información ya existe en el sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277311/compartir-archivo-mp3-de-la-carpeta-raw/277343#277343