# Error al generar PDF en Java Android

Tags: java, android-studio, itext

Hola amigos antes que nada gracias a los que lean y responda mi pregunta. Estoy implementado una APP Android nativa en la requiero generar un documento PDF, estoy tratando de hacerlo con la librería compileOnly `'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'` pero me esta generando un error al ejecutar la instancia de documento.

Este es el error que me esta presentando:

```
2019-07-15 11:47:19.948 26039-26039/com.example.boletas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.boletas, PID: 26039
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/itextpdf/text/Document;
        at com.example.boletas.PreloaderActivity.onCreate(PreloaderActivity.java:90)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1565)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1453)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.itextpdf.text.Document" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.boletas-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.example.boletas.PreloaderActivity.onCreate(PreloaderActivity.java:90) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1565) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1453)
```

Les dejo referencia del código que estoy aplicando:

```
String filename = "test.pdf";
try {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(folder + filename));
    document.open();
    document.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Gracias si en la respuesta me pudiera ayudar con referencia también a como configurar el ancho del PDF les agradecería.

Comment: Gracias por editar tu pregunta Irwing, en este caso define "  implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'" en tu build.gradle en lugar "compileOnly" saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del bloque `dependencies` de tu archivo `build.gradle` agrega la implementación de la library de esta forma:

```
dependencies{
    ...
    ...
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
}
```

**debes usar `implementation`.**

Recuerda que es importante definir el permiso :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

y realizar la petición manual del permiso:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)