# Como escribir un fichero txt en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, archivo, android-permissions

Buenas llevo intentando un par de dias escribir un fichero txt con mi app para poder leerlo posteriormente y usar esos datos, el problema es que no encuentro el fichero en la ruta que le pongo ni tampoco parece que escriba nada, tengo los permisos puestos en el manifest y tambien lo e intentado creando un metodo que llame a un objeto file

```
public static void statusFile(){

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    if(!fich.exists()){
        try {
            fich.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Pero tampoco funciona, e creado de forma estatica los parametros de la clase que serian los siguientes

```
static String direccion = "/storage/emulated/0/food.txt";
static File fich = new File(direccion);
```

En el manifest tengo puesto los siguientes permisos

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Para terminar he hecho el metodo escribir en el cual le paso los parametros a traves de un objeto llamado comida que lo relleno antes de enviarlo

```
    public static String writeFile(Food f){

    String linea = "";
    try {
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(direccion, true));
        linea += f.getNombre()+";";
        linea += f.getFechaCompra()+";";
        linea += f.getFechaCaducidad();

        br.write(linea);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return linea;
}
```

Comment: es muy importante revisar el LogCat.de esta forma puedes determinar el problema. recuerda que los permisos se deben requerir manualmente para dispositivos con Android 6.0 o superior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeramente el problema que impide crear un archivo es el permiso, para **dispositivos con sistema operativo mayor a 6.0 no es suficiente declarar el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` dentro de tu androidManifest.xml**:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

debes realizar la petición manual:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
} else {
    Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer y escribir!");
}
```

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

por cierto no es necesario el permiso `READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE`

---

De acuerdo a lo anterior, este método puede funcionar sin problema:

```
static String direccion = "/storage/emulated/0/food.txt";
static File fich = new File(direccion);

public static void statusFile(){

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    if(!fich.exists()){
        try {
            fich.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Pero te sugiero que en lugar de definir la ruta fija:

```
static String direccion = "/storage/emulated/0/food.txt";
```

**user `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` para obtener la ruta del directorio de almacenamiento externo, ya que la ruta puede no existir o ser diferente en algún modelo o tipo de dispositivo android**,

```
static String direccion = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/food.txt";
```

---

Si tu app apunta a targetSDK 29 el método  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` es marcado como obsoleto. Por lo tanto en este caso debes usar **[getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))**

```
static String direccion;
static File fich;

public static void statusFile(Context context){

    direccion = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/food32.txt";
    fich = new File(direccion);

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    if(!fich.exists()){
        try {
            fich.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error statusFile" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

de esta forma llamarías el método:

```
statusFile(getApplicationContext());
```

La diferencia aquí es que el archivo ahora se tendrá que guardar dentro del paquete de la aplicación.

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<paquete de aplicación>/files/food.txt
```

Comment: El metodo escribir esta bien, es para no tener que abrir un nuevo hilo, me esta dando "error", es decir cuando leo el fichero no me esta leyendo nada, y cuando compruebo el archivo no hay nada escrito, porque puede ser

Comment: Hola, lo recomendable es abrir una nueva pregunta, colocando el código que usas ahora para abrir el archivo, puedes hacer referencia a esta pregunta., realizala y te ayudo yo o la comunidad, saludos @CodeInBars

Comment: +1 por la respuesta, pero seria recomendable indicar que el método `getExternalStorageDirectory()` es obsoleto en el API 29

Comment: Cual sería el indicado @A.Palacio?

Comment: @CodeInBars Puedes seguir usando este método si tienes target a SDK 28 pero en un futuro sería Context.getExternalFilesDir(String) pero esto provocaría que la ruta donde guardes tu archivo cambiaría a /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<paquete de aplicación>/files/food.txt, edito mi respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Los permisos por lo que veo estan bien, pero puede que lo que falle es el código. Prueba con este

```
private void escribir(String datos,Context context) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(datos);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "Error: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```