# Como guardar un archivo en la Memoria Interna Fisica en Android

Tags: android

me gustaría saber como accedo y almaceno un archivo csv o txt en la memoria interna física del teléfono tal como lo muestro en la imagen para posterior mente ser accedido por otra aplicación[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear archivos en el almacenamiento interno debes usar [getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()), ejemplo:

```
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"ejemplo.txt");

        if(file.exists()){
            //Existe archivo
        }else{
            try {                    
                //Crea archivo 
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

no olvidar declarar y pedir manualmente el permiso :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Revisa:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

---

Te sugiero revisar también:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage?hl=es#InternalVsExternalStorage

Comment: Gracias por la solución, pero el detalle eran los permisos y a pesar de estar en el manifest este no lo reconocía. La razón es que uso el teléfono físico directo con android studio y explícitamente hay que dar los permisos de almacenamiento a través de configuración/aplicación etc....ya que al estar conectado al Android se obvia esta autorización. Me refiero a que aparece una ventana emergente preguntando si autoriza el uso de la memoria física. Luego de ese ajuste funcionó correctamente.