# Compatibilidad de dispositivos en la Play Store

Tags: java, android

Recientemente subí una app a la play store, y me aparece que solo es disponible para 5000 dispositivos, a diferencia de las otras apps que he subido que me aparece en el catálogo más de 18000 en disponibilidad.

He hecho varias modificaciones en el archivo manifest. A continuación le dejo parte del manifest.

//Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:extractNativeLibs="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
```

Tengo la Api min 16 y Max 30.

Este es mi archivo `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.global.descargas"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }



}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(":library")
    implementation project(":ffmpeg")

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVer"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVer"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidJunitVer"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVer"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0"
    implementation "com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.11'
    compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


}
```

Sospecho que es esta configuración,
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">`, si fuese esta, ¿cómo hago para mejorar, y lograr que sea compatible con los demás dispositivos?

Comment: Muéstrame el código de tu gradle

Comment: Oki.. va!. Lo agregaré a mi respuesta el codigo.

Comment: Debiste editar tu pregunta en vez de responderla.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque tienes definido `minSdkVersion 16` veo que tienes definido `targetSdkVersion 30`, si revisas la documentación esta indica:

> Después de actualizar su aplicación para que apunte a Android 11
> (nivel de API 30), el sistema ignora el atributo
> `requestLegacyExternalStorage` cuando su aplicación se ejecuta en
> dispositivos con Android 11, por lo que su aplicación debe estar lista
> para admitir el almacenamiento con alcance y para migrar los datos de
> la aplicación para los usuarios en esos dispositivos.

**Efectivamente como comentas el "problema" es el uso de `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` pero el problema real a resolver es hacer uso de métodos `getExternalFilesDir()` en lugar de `getExternalStorageDirectory()` para guardar los archivos en la memoria externa de tu dispositivo y usar `getFilesDir()` para guardar los archivos en la memoria interna del dispositivo.** Los dispositivos en los cuales no esta disponible tu app seguramente son los de API 30.

Para realizar estos cambios te sugiero revisar.

[Como guardar un archivo en la Memoria Interna Física en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316590/como-guardar-un-archivo-en-la-memoria-interna-fisica-en-android/316764#316764)

[¿Cómo crear carpeta en android 11?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425573/c%C3%B3mo-crear-carpeta-en-android-11/425683#425683)

[Método obsoleto getExternalStorageDirectory() en Android API 29 en adelante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417434/m%C3%A9todo-obsoleto-getexternalstoragedirectory-en-android-api-29-en-adelante/432306#432306)

[Error de permisos en Android 10 y superior(Android Studio) (Java)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414433/error-de-permisos-en-android-10-y-superiorandroid-studio-java/414551#414551)

Comment: Que tal hermano!. Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Interezante!!. Y muy valiosa para mi proyecto. A como me mencionó, actualicé todo los métodos que tenia usando como getExternalStorageDirectory(),  y lo sustituí por  getExternalFilesDir(), y del manifest quité la configuración android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true", esto me ayudo a optimizar y me mejorar mi código. Sin embargo la volví a colgar a la playstore. Y no obtuve ningún cambio en cuanto a la compatibilidad. Sigue sin aumentar dispositivos.  Saludos !!

Comment: tienes la Api min 16 y Max 30 cuales tenías anteriormente? En AndroidManifest.xml declaraste ahora algo nuevo para el uso de algún hardware por ejemplo camara? , me parece raro que con el cambio aún muestre una gran cantidad de dispositivos que no son compatibles.