# Visualizar y crear archivos pdf android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite, programación-móvil

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que me permite crear y ver archivos `.pdf` en ***Android Studio*** el problema es que al momento de ejecutar no me muestra el archivo creado. Ya he revisado varias veces las clases y los metodos. También le he pasado los permisos de escritura y lectura en el `manifest.xml`, agradezco su ayuda ya que no he podido encontrar el error que me permite visualizar el contenido de mi ***pdf*** creado.

Log:

> 2019-12-18 11:04:28.508 19560-19560/com.example.pdfcreator E/PDFView:
>   load pdf error java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or
>   directory
>       at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
>       at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:283)
>       at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:200)
>       at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.FileSource.createDocument(FileSource.java:37)
>       at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:53)
>       at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Mi clase templatePDF.class :

```
public class templatePDF {

    private Context context;
    private File pdfFile;
    private Document document;
    private PdfWriter pdfwriter;
    private Paragraph paragraph;
    private Font ftittle = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 20, Font.BOLD);
    private Font fSubtittle = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
    private Font fText = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD);
    private Font fHightittle = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 15, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED);


    public templatePDF(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void openDocument() {
        createPDF();
        try {
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            pdfwriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
            document.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("openDocument", e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void createPDF() {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "PDF");

        if (!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdirs();
        pdfFile = new File(folder, "templatePDF.pdf");
    }

    public void closeDocument() {
        document.close();
    }

    public void addMetaData(String tittle, String subject, String author) {
        document.addTitle(tittle);
        document.addSubject(subject);
        document.addAuthor(author);
    }

    public void addTittles(String tittle, String subtittle, String date) {
        try {
            paragraph = new Paragraph();
            addChildP(new Paragraph(tittle, ftittle));
            addChildP(new Paragraph(subtittle, fSubtittle));
            addChildP(new Paragraph("generado: " + date, fHightittle));
            paragraph.setSpacingAfter(30);
            document.add(paragraph);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("addTittles", e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void addChildP(Paragraph childParagraph) {
        childParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        paragraph.add(childParagraph);
    }

    public void addParagraph(String text) {
        try {
            paragraph = new Paragraph(text, fText);
            paragraph.setSpacingAfter(5);
            paragraph.setSpacingBefore(5);
            document.add(paragraph);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("addParagraph", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void createTable(String[] header, ArrayList<String[]> clients) {
        try {
            paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.setFont(fText);
            PdfPTable pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(header.length);
            pdfPTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
            PdfPCell pdfPCell;
            int indexC = 0;
            while (indexC < header.length) {
                pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(header[indexC++], fSubtittle));
                pdfPCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                pdfPCell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GREEN);
                pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);
            }
            for (int indexR = 0; indexR < clients.size(); indexR++) {
                String[] row = clients.get(indexR);
                for (indexC = 0; indexC < header.length; indexC++) {
                    pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row[indexC]));
                    pdfPCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    pdfPCell.setFixedHeight(40);
                    pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);
                }
            }

            paragraph.add(pdfPTable);
            document.add(paragraph);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("createTable", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void viewPDF() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewPdfActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("patch", pdfFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Mi clase ViewPdfActivity.class:

```
public class ViewPdfActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PDFView pdfView;
    private File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pdf);
        pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle!=null) {
            file = new File(bundle.getString("patch", ""));
        }

        pdfView.fromFile(file)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .enableAntialiasing(true)
            .load();
    }
```

Mi clase MainActivity.class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] header = {"Id", "Nombre", "Apellido"};
    private String shortText = "Hola";
    private String LongText = "Esto es una prueba test de viewer pdf generador de archivos en pdf";
    private templatePDF templatePDF;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        templatePDF = new templatePDF(getApplicationContext());
        templatePDF.openDocument();
        templatePDF.addMetaData("Clientes", "Ventas", "Marines");
        templatePDF.addTittles("Tienda Prubas", "Clientes", "13/12/2019");
        templatePDF.addParagraph(shortText);
        templatePDF.addParagraph(LongText);
        templatePDF.createTable(header, getClients());
        templatePDF.closeDocument();

    }

    public void pdfView(View view) {
        templatePDF.viewPDF();
    }

    private ArrayList<String[]> getClients() {
        ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();

        rows.add(new String[]{"1", "Peter", "Guti"});
        rows.add(new String[]{"2", "maria", "Guti"});
        rows.add(new String[]{"3", "jose", "Guti"});
        rows.add(new String[]{"4", "marcos", "Guti"});

        return rows;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisando tu código, veo que creas directorio y archivo pero obtienes:

> PDFView: load pdf error java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or
>   directory

Para leer/escribir archivos es necesario definir en tu AndroidManifest.xml el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

pero en este caso  si marca error asegurate de requerir los permisos manualmente:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android)

Si lo anterior queda resuelto ahora te comento que hay un detalle en tu código, **Estas creando el directorio pero no el archivo, para crearlo puedes usar el método `createNewFile()`** :

```
private void createPDF() {

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "PDF");

    if (!folder.exists()){
        //Crea directorio
        folder.mkdirs();
        pdfFile = new File(folder, "templatePDF.pdf");

        //Crea archivo
        try {
          pdfFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

---

***Actualización:**

En realidad la ruta del PDF no se esta recibiendo y esto es debido a que la variable que contiene el archivo solo es diferente de null cuando no se ha creado el archivo, cuando se crea el archivo nunca se inicializa, debes obtener el archivo y verificar si este existe, si es así ahora podrás enviar la ruta, esto lo puedes realizar en el método `viewPDF()`:

```
public void viewPDF() {    

   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"+  "PDF", "templatePDF.pdf");
    if (file.exists()){
       //Archivo existe.
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewPdfActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("patch", file.getAbsoluteFile());
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intent);
      }else{
       Log.e("templatePDF", "Archivo no existe!");
      }

}
```

Comment: ya agregue el metodo creteNewFile() como me indicaste, ya le pase los permisos en el manifest.xml y tambien lo hice manualmente. Pero aun sigue sin mostrarme el pdf y me muestra el mismo error...

Comment: Revisa los permisos @ProgramadorJunior de hecho puedes ver las aplicaciones en configuración, busca tu aplicación y verifica si tiene activados los permisos de almacenamiento.

Comment: ya verifique y si los tiene activados...no entiendo que pasa

Comment: Ok entonces que te parece si revisas cuando obtienes el bundle si existe el archivo: file = new File(bundle.getString("patch", ""));

Comment: Efectivamente amigo..no esta pasando el archivo en el bundle

Comment: @ProgramadorJunior ah ya veo, tienes un flujo en el cual no se obtiene la información del archivo, revisa la edición a mi respuesta.