# Error al intentar guardar imagen en almacenamiento interno con un boton en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso, android-context, guardar

Estimados: en Android Studio estoy teniendo un inconveniente al querer almacenar una imagen después de hacer clic en un botón de un activity (que no es el principal).
Al clickear en dicho botón me arroja el error que no se pudo guardar la imagen mediante un mensaje Toast. Para guardar generé una clase llamada "Guardar" y la imagen a almacenar la tomo desde el activity principal con Picasso mediante un ImageView.

Código del segundo activity denominado "Segundo":

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Segundo extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSave;
    ImageView imagen;
    Context contexto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_segundo);
        contexto = this;
        imagen = findViewById(R.id.Imagen_IV);
        btnSave = findViewById(R.id.BtnGuardarS);

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load("http://192.168.0.2/Carpeta/imagen_draw.png")
                .error(R.drawable.no_guardo)
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .into(imagen);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imagen.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = imagen.getDrawingCache();

                Guardar save_imagen = new Guardar();
                save_imagen.Almacenar_Img(contexto , bitmap);

            }
        });


 }
}
```

Código de la clase "Guardar":

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Guardar {

    private Context the_this;
    private String nombreCarpeta = "/Carpeta";
    private String nombreDelArchivo = "imagen_guardada";

    public void Almacenar_Img(Context context, Bitmap ImageToSave) {

        the_this = context;
        String ruta_file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + nombreCarpeta;
        String fecha_actual = getCurrentDateAndTime();
        File dir = new File(ruta_file);

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        File archivo = new File(dir, nombreDelArchivo + fecha_actual + ".jpg");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(archivo);

            ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            confirmar_Creacion_File(archivo);
            SiGuardar();
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            NoGuardar();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            NoGuardar();
        }

    }

    private void confirmar_Creacion_File(File archivo){
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(the_this,
                new String[] { archivo.toString() } , null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String ruta, Uri uri) {
                    }
                });
    }

    private String getCurrentDateAndTime() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-­ss");
        String formato_fecha = df.format(c.getTime());
        return formato_fecha;
    }

    private void NoGuardar() {
        Toast.makeText(the_this, "No se guardo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void SiGuardar() {
        Toast.makeText(the_this, "Código guardado en la galería.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

A su vez, en el manifiesto están declaradas las lineas correspondientes a los permisos de WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE y READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
El error que se genera se produce en el método NoGuardar.
Agradezco toda ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Saludos a la distancia!

Comment: Y qué excepción te salta?

Comment: Es importante siempre revisar el LogCat y ahí puedes encontrar detalles sobre el error.

Answer (score 0):

Realizaste la definición de los permisos en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

en realidad `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` no es necesario definirlo.

**El problema aquí es que la petición del permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, también debe realizarse de forma manual** para dispositivos con Android 6.0 o posterior.

```
  int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
```

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android)