# ¿Cómo eliminar un archivo en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

necesito eliminar una imagen que esta en el almacenamiento interno del dispositivo hasta ahora tengo este código que me sirve para saber si la carpeta existe,
El detalle es que no me elimina el archivo y en la parte del .delete() aparece una advertencia que dice: "Result of 'File.delete()' is ignored"

```
private void eliminarQr(){

    try {
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Car_id");
        if (dir.isDirectory()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"SI ES DIRECTORIO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new File(dir,"PLACA_100.JPG").delete();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"NO ES DIRECTORIO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(this,"NO ELIMINADO "+ e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente, sobre el mensaje:

```
"Result of 'File.delete()' is ignored"
```

este se debe a que al usar el método `.delete()`, este retorna un valor de tipo `boolean` que determina si pudo o no eliminar el archivo, en este caso no lo estas asignando a una variable, no lo estas usando por esta razón la IDE te indica que el valor será ignorado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Para realizar la eliminación de archivos necesitas principalmente 2 cosas, primeramente definir y requerir manualmente el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external)

segundo, la ruta del archivo que deseas eliminar debe ser correcta, he visto comúnmente que el problema es que la ruta a el archivo no es especificada correctamente o el nombre del archivo es incorrecto y esa es la razón por la cual no se elimina el archivo.

**Tu código es correcto para eliminar el archivo, pero te sugiero imprimas el valor de `dir` y revises si la ruta y nombre del archivo son correctos.**

En mi caso por ejemplo la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo sería:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Car_id/PLACA_100.JPG
```