# como eliminar todos los archivos dentro del directorio download android con java

Tags: java, android-studio

```
public void deleteDirectory(View view) {
    File download = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"Download");;
    if(download.exists()) {
        Log.i("TAG",""+download.exists());
        Log.i("TAG",download.getAbsolutePath());
        File[] files = download.listFiles();
        Log.i("TAG",""+files.length);
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                File Dir = new File(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                File[] filesInDir = Dir.listFiles();
                //Elimina archivos de directorio.
                for(int j = 0; j < filesInDir.length; j++){
                    Log.i("TAG", "Elmina en dir " + filesInDir[j]);
                    filesInDir[j].delete();
                }
            }
            else {
                //Elimina archivo.
                Log.i("TAG", "Elmina archivo " + files[i]);
                files[i].delete();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

necesito eliminar todos los archivos que están en la carpeta download de Android,pero no muestra mas que el log del permiso para leer, ademas de un warning que dice "File.delete() is ignore"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con respecto a el mensaje:

> "Result of 'File.delete()' is ignored"

no es un error, simplemente es un mensaje ya que el método `.delete()` retorna un valor de tipo boolean que determina si pudo o no eliminar el archivo, en este caso no lo estas asignando a una variable, no lo estas usando por esta razón la IDE te indica que el valor será ignorado.

Revisa:

¿Cómo eliminar un archivo en Android Studio?
[¿Cómo eliminar un archivo en Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366295/c%c3%b3mo-eliminar-un-archivo-en-android-studio/366346#366346)

Para eliminar los archivos dentro de un directorio te sugiero primeramente usar este método para obtener el path del directorio de almacenamiento externo, incluso revisa si se encuentra montado:

```
public static String getExternalStorage(Context ctx) {
        String path = "";
        if (Utilities.isNullorEmpty(path)) {
            String pathExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(pathExternalStorage)) {
                path = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/";
            } else {
                path = ctx.getFilesDir().toString() + "/";
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Ahora usas el método anterior para obtener el directorio y de esta forma eliminarías los archivos:

```
  public void deleteDirectory(View view) {
        String tempfilepath = getExternalStorage(view.getContext()) + "Download";
        try {
            File grTempFiles = new File(tempfilepath);
            if (grTempFiles.exists()) {
                File[] files = grTempFiles.listFiles();
                if (grTempFiles.isDirectory() && files != null) {
                    int numofFiles = files.length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numofFiles; i++) {
                        files[i].delete();
                    }
                }
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "deleteDirectory: Failed to onCreate directory  " + tempfilepath + " for an unknown reason.");
        }
    }
```

Recuerda que es demasiado importante definir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` y solicitar la petición manual de los permisos:

[Petición permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external/24934#24934)

Comment: por alguna razón solo me esta tomando imágenes

Comment: esto obtiene todos los archivos: File[] files = grTempFiles.listFiles(); , si solo elimina las imágenes es que dentro de /files/Download/, me parece que si estas guardando otro tipo de archivos, estos los guardas en otra ubicación, tal vez en /files/

Comment: el problema es que en android 11 para arriba hay que pedir otros permisos para modificar todo tipo de archivos