# ¿Como acceder al archivo en memoria?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

tengo un problema con mi app Android, me arroja una excepción de (No such file or directory)
, lo que trato de hacer es consultar la base de datos interna, y hacer un tipo respaldo dentro de la memoria interna del celular, en una carpeta de logs, que ya tengo creada, ya tengo los permisos en manifest correspondientes, estoy usando SUGAR para sqlite, cabe mencionar que la base interna que tengo en "data" funciona correctamente. Espero me puedan ayudar gracias, anexo el codigo aqui.

```
public boolean importDBHidden() throws IOException
{
    boolean success = false;
    FileChannel src = null;
    FileChannel dst = null;
    try{
        File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File appDir = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
            } else {
                Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
            }
        }

        if (sdDir.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "com.example.filesdata" + "//databases//" + "asistenciaSocial.db";
            String backupDBPath = sdDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/asistencia_LOGS/DataBase Backup/System_bat.db";
            File backupDB = new File(appDir, currentDBPath);
            File currentDB = new File(sdDir, backupDBPath);
            dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            success = true;
            Log.v(TAG, "Creado Success");
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        success = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "Error1: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try{
            if (src != null){
                src.close();
            }
        } catch (Throwable e)
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "Error2: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if (dst != null){
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema :

> No such file or direct

se debe a dos causas:

• **No tienes permisos definidos para leer y escribir, en este caso debes definir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` en el `AndroidManifest.xml` y realizas su petición manualmente**, revisa:
[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external)

**• El archivo o su ruta en donde se supone se encuentra no existe.** Para esto debes depurar y revisar si existe

En esta parte noto un detalle, no debes usar  `sdDir.getAbsolutePath()` para formar el `backupDBPath`, ya que este se define cuando se crea el archivo. También podrías hacer uso del LogCat para imprimir si en realidad se crea el archivo en base a la ruta deseada.

```
...
...
String currentDBPath = "/data/" + "com.example.filesdata" + "/databases/" + "asistenciaSocial.db";
// String backupDBPath = sdDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/asistencia_LOGS/DataBase Backup/System_bat.db";
String backupDBPath =  "/asistencia_LOGS/DataBase Backup/System_bat.db";
File backupDB = new File(appDir, currentDBPath);
File currentDB = new File(sdDir, backupDBPath);
 if(backupDB.exists()){
     Log.i("Mensaje", "Existe el archivo: "  + backupDB.getAbsolutePath());
}else{
     Log.e("Mensaje", "No existe el archivo: "  + backupDB.getAbsolutePath());
}
if(currentDB.exists()){
     Log.i("Mensaje", "Existe el archivo: "  + currentDB.getAbsolutePath());
}else{
     Log.e("Mensaje", "No existe el archivo: "  + currentDB.getAbsolutePath());
}
...
...
```