# Como borrar las fotos guardadas en la carpeta Pictures Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Tengo una pequena app donde envio por correo la foto tomada, esa foto se almacena en la galeria, todo bien pero quisiera saber si hay manera de borrarlas.

Se que la ruta es en Pictures DIRECTORY_PICTURES

Lo intente hacer con una funcion que recorre los datos

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
        if( path.exists() ) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
        return(path.delete());
    }
```

Pero al querer al llegar a esa parte la aplicacion se cierra

La manera en que lo mando llamar es

```
File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                deleteDirectory(path);
```

No se si pudieran ayudarme con esto

Comment: si se cierra, cual es el error mostrado en el LogCat? acostumbra agregar esta información.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes tener definido el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, tanto en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` como realizar la petición manual, puedes revisar:

[Petición permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24934/95)

El no poder leer el contenido de directorios es principalmente problema con falta de permisos, si no lo tienes entonces en esta linea obtendrías como valor del array files null:

```
File[] files = path.listFiles();
```

define los permisos.

Para obtener el path donde se guardan las fotos del dispositivo usa:

```
 File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath());
```

y en el caso de tu método puedes realizarlo de esta forma, no creo conveniente que sea recursivo tu método, por cierto la última linea: `path.delete()` no es necesaría ya que no podrás eliminar el directorio Pictures ya que es de sistema.

Usa el siguiente método:

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if(path.exists()) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                File Dir = new File(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                File[] filesInDir = Dir.listFiles();
                //Elimina archivos de directorio.
                for(int j = 0; j < filesInDir.length; j++){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Elmina en dir " + filesInDir[j]);
                    filesInDir[j].delete();
                }
            }
            else {
                //Elimina archivo.
                Log.i(TAG, "Elmina archivo " + files[i]);
                files[i].delete();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;//return(path.delete());
}
```