# Como asignar una imagen desde una ruta especifica de almacenamiento externo

Tags: java, android

Quiero asignar unas imágenes a diferentes `ImageView` mediante esta linea, lo repito por cada `ImageView`, pero me tira error:
CODIGO:

```
    Uri myUriOriginal = (Uri.parse("/Android/data/com.example.example/files/Pictures/Imagen.jpg"));
    imgviewImagenOriginal.setImageURI(myUriOriginal);
```

Esa imagen es imagen tomada desde la camara; añado codigo:

```
private void TomarFotoCamara(){
    Intent camaraintent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(camaraintent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
        File fotofile=null;
        try {
            fotofile = Creararchivofoto();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(fotofile!=null){
            Uri fotouri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.example",fotofile);
            camaraintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fotouri);
            startActivityForResult(camaraintent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}
//METODO: Guardar foto de la camara - getExternalFilesDir()   -  getExternalStorageDirectory()
public File Creararchivofoto() throws IOException {
    File almacenamiento= getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File foto = new File(almacenamiento, "Imagen.jpg");
    guardarimagen = foto.getAbsolutePath();
    return foto;
}
```

Comment: Que error Juan, recuerda que es importante mencionar esta información en tus preguntas para que sea de ayuda a más personas que tengan la misma problematica, saludos.

Comment: se me cierra la app

Comment: Ok, siempre Revisa el LogCat Juan, me parece que el problema puede ser porque la ruta o la imagen no existe, es importante validar,  agregue una respuesta., saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No debes definir directamente el path :

> "/Android/data/com.example.example/files/"

Debes obtenerlo mediante el uso de `getExternalFilesDir()` de esta forma :

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/";
```

---

Si tu archivo se encuentra dentro de :

> "/Android/data/com.example.example/files/Pictures/Imagen.jpg"

Obtén el archivo de esta forma, es importante agregues código para validar si tu archivo existe en verdad y de esta forma determinar agregar la imagen a tu `ImageView`:

```
  //Crea archivo a partir de ruta y nombre.
  File myFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/Pictures/" + "Imagen.jpg");
  //Verifica que exista.
   if(myFile.exists()){
       //Existe, carga archivo en ImageView.
       imgviewImagenOriginal.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(myFile));
   }else{
       //No existe archivo....
   }
```

---

Es muy importante que para poder leer y escribir se asegure tener definido el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

y realizar la petición manual, revisa:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external/24934#24934)

Comment: Ok Juan, por eso se cerraba tu app, revisa primeramente con un explorador de archivos en donde exactamente tienes tu archivo, tal vez no tiene ese nombre o extensión o esta en otro directorio, primero úbicalo en tu disco.

Comment: Si esta bien , por que esa ruta y nombre de la imagen que quiero, se me genera al momento de tomar la foto con la cámara - según Android developer. (Estoy realizando una ecualización de histograma y busco que solo los resultados se me muestren en otro activity incluyendo la imagen original)

Comment: Ya revisado lo digitado, corregido, se me cierra la app igual

Comment: Tu imagen con nombre "Imagen.jpg" se encuentra en : "/Android/data/com.example.example/files/Pictures/" ??? El código que te agrego en realidad revisa que exista ese archivo si dice que no existe es porque no existe o esta en otro lugar, revisalo con el file explorer que en verdad se haya creado la imagen ahí.

Comment: Si se encuentra, ya revise, solo se me cierra el aplicativo

Comment: Si vas a desarrollar en Android es super importante el uso del LogCat @JUANMIGUELDIAZHERNANDEZ con esto puedes detectar y corregir errores de una forma más rápida. En este caso si el archivo en realidad existe en la ruta definida entonces, lo único que faltaría sería revisar el permiso, edite la respuesta.

Comment: Ya encontré el error, estaba en otro lado; y si su código si me ayudo, gracias !!!