# Crear imagen PNG en Android Studio (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Bien, tengo una aplicación con la cual intento crear una imagen PNG para luego ser enviada por Whatsapp.

Lo probé antes y me andaba lo mas bien, pero ahora dejó de funcionar y dentro del método try/catch me arroja al catch, a continuación dejo el código el cual captura la imagen y la convierte en png: (Generando_imagen es solo un layout con un progressbar) quisiera saber cual es el error y si se puede solucionar, el error que me arroja en modo debug es este: *(abajo dejo error en modo debug completo)*:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/01-10-2020.png (Permission denied)

No se si ese será concretamente el error, pero es lo que pude ver.

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    ocultar_texto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ocultar_botones.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Generando_imagen.start(buscar_2.this);
    Date fecha = new Date();

    try {

        String mPath = getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + fecha + ".png";
        direccion_imagen = "/" + fecha + ".png";
        View u = findViewById(R.id.constrain_screen);
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        u.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();



    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR al intentar generar imagen .png", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ocultar_texto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ocultar_botones.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imagen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Generando_imagen.stop();
            sendImageWhatsApp(direccion_imagen);
        }
    }, 6000); // 6 segundos de "delay"
}
```

Les dejo también mi layout aquí abajo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constrain_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLinear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linear_botones"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#3C5C97"
        android:text="@string/espacio"
        android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView36"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3C5C97"
            android:text="@string/espacio"
            android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF867D"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNumero"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewApellido"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewFecha"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#3C5C97"
            android:text="@string/espacio"
            android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA1"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA2"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA3"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA4"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA5"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA6"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA7"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA8"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA9"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB1"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB2"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB3"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB4"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB5"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB6"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB7"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB8"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB9"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC1"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC2"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC3"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC4"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC5"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC6"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC7"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC8"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC9"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#3C5C97"
            android:text="@string/espacio"
            android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#3C5C97"
        android:text="@string/espacio"
        android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_botones"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearTexto"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_boton_cancelar"
        android:onClick="Salir" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button29"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_boton_compartir_imagen"
        android:onClick="Comprueba_conexion_internet" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_boton_editar"
        android:onClick="Editar" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_boton_borrar"
        android:onClick="Borrar_dialog" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearTexto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView43"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/cancelar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView69"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/compartir_imagen"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView42"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/editar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView41"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/borrar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagen"
    android:layout_width="545dp"
    android:layout_height="116dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLinear"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/titulo_imagen" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error completo que aparece en modo debug:**

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Fri Dec 04 13:41:30 GMT-03:00 2020.png (Permission denied)
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
> W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:308)
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:238)
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:180)
> W/System.err:     at com.example.screenapp.Activity_Buscar.buscar_2.takeScreenshot(buscar_2.java:355)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> W/System.err:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600)
> W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577)
> at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912)
> W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)

Comment: Si tienes accesso a la vista es mejor que te crees un canvas con el bitmap , y le des u.draw(canvas), le pasas el canvas, el bitmap el mismo tamaño que la vista. No recuerdo bien lo de drawing cache pero en oreo creo que es difrente cambia y es depreceado creo. Fijate si tiene una funcion getdrawablecache o algo asi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad como lo mencionas este es el problema principal:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/01-10-2020.png (Permission denied) -

Tiene dos causas:

- No existe el archivo.
- No tienes permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE definidos, recuerda que ahora debes definirlos en el `AndroidManifest.xml` y requerirlo manualmente.

Al parecer no tienes problemas en obtener el *Drawable* pero si para crear el Bitmap, debes requerir los permisos, revisa:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external/24934#24934)

Comment: Genial me sirvió, más abajo comenté como lo resolví gracias a tu respuesta. Otra pregunta que por ahí sabes resolver, cuando creo mi imagen PNG se crea en tipo vertical, sabes alguna forma mediante código de girar la imagen 90 grados? Para que así se vea horizontal y la imagen sea más grande. Gracias @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, mi problema es que no le pedia los permisos al usuario. en el Manifest tenia ambos permisos (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) la solucion fue agregar en mi aplicacion el siguiente codigo:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //No se tiene permisos
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        //Se tiene permisos
        Comprueba_conexion_internet(); //funcion a ejecutar si el usuario da permisos de almacenamiento
    }
```