# Error de permisos en Android 10 y superior(Android Studio) (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Dejo enlace a una pregunta realizada y resuelta anteriormente.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/412202/crear-imagen-png-en-android-studio-java)

Bien, como mencione, el problema de crear una imagen .png y compartirla a través de WhatsApp esta resuelto, eran problemas de permisos de lectura. El problema quedo resuelto y anda bien hasta la versión 9 de Android, en versiones 10 y superiores me sigue arrojando el error:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/foto.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

No se si tengo que pedirle al usuario otro tipo de permiso o es algún tipo de permiso que va en el *Manifest*

Dejo mis líneas de código:

```
//Toma ScreenShot y crea imagen PNG
private void takeScreenshot() {

    ocultar_texto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ocultar_botones.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Generando_imagen.start(buscar_2.this);

    try {

        String mPath = getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "foto" + ".png";
        direccion_imagen = "/" + "foto" + ".png";
        View u = findViewById(R.id.constrain_screen);
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        u.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();



    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR al intentar generar imagen .png", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ocultar_texto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ocultar_botones.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imagen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Generando_imagen.stop();
            sendImageWhatsApp(direccion_imagen);
        }
    }, 6000); // 6 segundos de "delay"
}


//Pide al usuario permisos de almacenamiento
public void Pedir_permisos_almacenamiento(View view){
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
        takeScreenshot();
    }
}
```

Abajo mis permisos ingresados en el Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Función para exportar imagen a través de *WhatsApp*:

```
//Envia imagen PNG a traves de WhatsApp
private void sendImageWhatsApp(String nombreImagen) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + nombreImagen));
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no esta instalado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**El problema es que el método [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) es obsoleto en la API 29 (Android 10)**

Para dispositivos con Android 10 o posterior debes usar:

[**getExternalFilesDir()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))

> Devuelve la ruta absoluta al directorio en el dispositivo de
> almacenamiento externo / compartido principal donde la aplicación
> puede colocar los archivos persistentes que posee.
>
> Android / data / data /<Paquete de aplicación>/
>
> Estos archivos son internos de las aplicaciones y, por lo general, el
> usuario no puede verlos como medios.

Ejemplo:

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
```

---

Una solución momentánea sería usar:

Puedes usar `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` seria una solución momentánea ya que en algún momento se tiene que cambiar a usar `getExternalFilesDir()`.

```
<manifest ... >
<!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
     Android 10 or higher. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Revisa

[Cómo inhabilitar temporalmente el almacenamiento específico](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage)

Comment: En mi caso solo bastaria con cambiar String mPath = getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "foto" + ".png";

Y en su lugar escribir String mPath = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/" + "foto" + ".png"; ???

Comment: Encontré esta solución, que seria agregar la siguiente linea de código en el Manifest. android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" 
Por ahora me anda bien, pero no se si esta mal usarlo o es una opción a considerar...

Comment: Puedes usar android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true seria una solución momentanea, en algún momento tienes que cambiar a getExternalFilesDir, puedes usar String mPath = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/" + "foto" + ".png";

Comment: Bien, entonces usare String mPath = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/" + "foto" + ".png"; Y luego tendré que buscar la ruta de almacenamiento de mi archivo para poder enviarlo por WhatsApp. Actualizo con mi código para compartir la imagen a través de WhatsApp para poder resolver la linea de código que me falla.