# Método obsoleto getExternalStorageDirectory() en Android API 29 en adelante

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código *(en API 28 y anteriores anda bien)* y no puedo lograr cambiarlo para usarlo en API 29 en adelante. ¿Alguna ayuda?

por lo que tengo entendido el método `getExternalStorageDirectory()` quedo obsoleto en la **API 29** en adelante. Sé que como reemplazo apareció el método `getExternalFilesDir` pero no logro entenderlo por completo.

En resumen la aplicación crea una imagen .PNG de ciertos datos ingresados por el usuario y la quiero compartir a través de WhatsApp.

Código de mi Activity (Función que crea la imagen y función que la comparte por WhatsApp):

```
//Pide al usuario permisos de almacenamiento
public void Pedir_permisos_almacenamiento(View view){
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
        takeScreenshot();
    }
}

//Toma ScreenShot y crea imagen PNG
private void takeScreenshot() {

    ocultar_texto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ocultar_botones.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Generando_imagen.start(buscar_2.this);

    try {

        String mPath = getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "foto" + ".png";
        direccion_imagen = "/" + "foto" + ".png";
        View u = findViewById(R.id.constrain_screen);
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        u.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR al intentar generar imagen .png", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ocultar_texto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ocultar_botones.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imagen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Generando_imagen.stop();
            sendImageWhatsApp(direccion_imagen);
        }
    }, 6000); // 6 segundos de "delay"
}

//Envia imagen PNG a traves de WhatsApp
private void sendImageWhatsApp(String nombreImagen) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + nombreImagen));
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no esta instalado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes dejar de usar `getExternalStorageDirectory()` ya que cuando compiles tu app para Android 11 este método incluso probablemente no exista, el cambio lo tienes que realizar en este punto:

```
 String mPath = getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "foto" + ".png";
```

debes cambiar a `getExternalFilesDir()` de esta forma:

```
 String mPath = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + "foto" + ".png";
```

Aquí la diferencia radica en que al usar  `getExternalStorageDirectory()` podrías guardar el archivo fuera de la estructura de tu aplicación

```
/storage/emulated/0/foto.png
```

**pero ahora al usar `getExternalFilesDir()` tu archivo se creara dentro del directorio `/files` que a su vez se encuentra dentro del directorio definido por el `package name` de la aplicación**:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/foto.png
```

Revisa esta respuesta:

[**Cambiar getExternalStorageDirectory() que es obsoleto en la API 29 (Android 10) por getExternalFilesDir()**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/414551/95)