# Porque Android Studio para leer un archivo de texto No Funciona en un Equipo Galaxy A10 de SAMSUNG…

Tags: android-studio

al parecer es problema de FileReader que no lee el archivo csv no estoy seguro, ya verifique que exista el archivo pero no lo puede leer. todo esto pasa en celulares o tablet samsung con android 10 pero con otros modelos y versiones de android anteriores a 10 si funcionan el mismo codigo.

```
File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents");
//File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Serviforestal");
String archivoPedidos = carpeta.toString() + "/" + "PedidosOK.csv";
boolean isCreate = false;
pedirPermisos();
if(!carpeta.exists()) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NO EXISTE LA CARPETA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else  {
    if (archivoPedidos!=null){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SI EXISTE EL ARCHIVO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String cadena;
        String[] arreglo;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(archivoPedidos);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "INCLUSO LO ASIGNA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Pedido pedido=null;

            while((cadena = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                arreglo = cadena.split(",");
                String lote=arreglo[4].toString();
                pedido=new Pedido();
                ConeccionSQLiteHelper admin = new ConeccionSQLiteHelper(getContext(), "serviforestal.db", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
                registro.put("numero", arreglo[0].toString());
                registro.put("fecha", arreglo[1].toString());
                registro.put("finca", arreglo[2].toString());
                registro.put("lote",arreglo[3].toString());
                registro.put("equipo", arreglo[4].toString());
                registro.put("supervisor", arreglo[5].toString());
                registro.put("jefeproceso", arreglo[6].toString());
                registro.put("jefelinea", arreglo[7].toString());
                registro.put("estimadop", Integer.valueOf(arreglo[8].toString()));
                registro.put("estimadot", arreglo[9].toString());
                registro.put("producidop", arreglo[10].toString());
                registro.put("producidot", arreglo[11].toString());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Pedido: "+arreglo[1]+" "+arreglo[2]+" "+arreglo[3], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NO SE IMPORTO EXITOSAMENTE, NO RECONOCE ARCHIVO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else  {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NO EXISTE EL ARCHIVO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: para mejorar la privacidad del usuario `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` fue deprecado en android 10 y ya no se permite acceder a archivos fuera del directorio de tu app usando su ruta completa. Debes migrar a una de las nuevas [alternativas](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Si tu app esta dirigida para sistema operativo Android 10 (`targetSdkVersion 29`) o posterior debes dejar de usar el método `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

[Método obsoleto getExternalStorageDirectory() en Android API 29 en adelante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417434/m%C3%A9todo-obsoleto-getexternalstoragedirectory-en-android-api-29-en-adelante)

debes cambiar a usar el método `getExternalFilesDir()` de esta forma:

```
File carpeta = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() +  "/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents");
```

Pero debes tomar en cuenta que ahora la ruta de donde se deben leer o guardar archivos cambiara por ejemplo a:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents
```