# Como se crea una carpeta en memoria (Disco) interna de android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, archivo, filewriter

Estoy intentando crear una carpeta en la memoria interna (Ojo no en la `RAM`, en el disco donde se persisten los archivos) del teléfono `Android`.

Nota: estoy programando en `Java`.

```
package com.example.liferegisterdiary;

/*
*
* This is a file and folder controller 2021
* Here you create and read files and folders.
*
* */

import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.File;

public class FileFolderController {
    public boolean mkdirStatus;

    public FileFolderController() {
        mkdirStatus = true;
        makeDir("ejemplo");
    }

    public void makeDir(String folderR) {
        try {
            File newFolder = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), folderR);
            mkdirStatus = mkdirStatus & newFolder.mkdirs();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mkdirStatus = mkdirStatus & false;
        }
    }

    public String health() {
        return "Estoy en el controlador de archivos y carpetas...." + mkdirStatus;
    }
}
```

Lo que necesito hacer es crear una carpeta en el `root` principal de la memoria interna del teléfono, Ojo: no en la `microSD` la necesito en la memoria interna... El problema es que ni siquiera me deja crear una carpeta en /data...

Alguien podría ayudarme????

Nota: voy a dejar un ejemplo en `Python` de como se crear una carpeta en `Windows`:

```
import os
from os import scandir

if not os.path.isdir(self.rutaDelProyecto+"\\DATA"): # No existe la carpera creelas
    os.mkdir(self.rutaDelProyecto+"\\DATA")
```

Este programa es muy simple: solo verifica si existe la carpeta data y en caso de que no exista crea esa carpeta...
Lo que yo quiero lograr en `Android` es lo mismo... como crear una carpeta... lo que pasa es que he visto muchos tutoriales e intentado mil cosas y no consigo crear una carpeta ayudaaa por favor.

Comment: las carpetas solo se pueden crear en disco... o como temporal en algún sitio pero en memoria no tiene sentido; incluso si fueses a trabajar con un string o dato de archivo lo creas y lo manipulas en memoria y luego lo depositas en el directorio deseado... o  al revés lo creas en el directorio deseado y en ese lugar lo manipulas ... pero directorio en ram ... ningún lenguaje que yo conozca hace eso o si lo hace no le veo provecho...

Comment: Hola, tienes toda la razón. Lo que quiero hacer es crear una carpeta en el disco principal del dispositivop movil.

Comment: bueno hay si te toca investigar que dice la documentación para kottlin y java en android estudio de como se implementa la creación de directorios ... https://www.google.com/search?q=android+studio+create+directory+internal+storage&oq=android+studio+create+directory&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i19l5j0i19i22i30l4.8575j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ello hay que importar el contexto desde la main_activity

// Main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Context context = this;
    fileFolderController = new FileFolderController(context);
    //bla bla bla...
}
```

// Luego en la controladora de carpetas hay que invocar la ruta

```
package com.example.liferegisterdiary;

import android.content.Context;
import java.io.File;

/*
*
* This is a file and folder controller 2021
* Here you create and read files and folders.
*
* */
public class FileFolderController {
    Context context;
    public boolean mkdirStatus;

    public FileFolderController(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mkdirStatus = true;
    }

    public void makeDir(String folderR) {}

    public String health() {
        String intStorageDir = this.context.getExternalFilesDir("") + "";
        File newFolder = new File(intStorageDir, "LifeRegisterData");

        if (newFolder.mkdirs()) {
            return "Estoy en el controlador de filas y carpetas.... Carpeta loco>>   " + intStorageDir;
        } else {
            return "Estoy en el controlador de filas y carpetas.... No hice nada" + intStorageDir;
        }
    }
}
```

Y con esto quedara creada en /MemoriaInterna/Android/data/com.nombreAPP/files/CarpetaQueSeDeseaCrear

Comment: Hola getExternalFilesDir() no se usa para crear un directorio o archivo en el almacenamiento interno.

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas crear un archivo o directorio en la memoria interna debes usar [**getFilesDir()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) :

```
String directoryPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "newfoldername";
File myDirectory = new File(directoryPath);
```

Si esto lo quieres realizar en otro archivo que no es la `Activity` debes enviar como parámetro el contexto

```
  public class FileFolderController {

    Context context;
    public boolean mkdirStatus;

    public FileFolderController(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        mkdirStatus = true;
    }

    public void makeDir(String folderR){

    }

    public String health(){

        //Crea directorio en almacenamiento interno.
        String intStorageDir = this.context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "LifeRegisterData";
        File newFolder = new File(intStorageDir);

        if (newFolder.mkdirs()){
            return "Estoy en el controlador de filas y carpetas.... Carpeta loco>>   " + intStorageDir;
        }else{
            return "Estoy en el controlador de filas y carpetas.... No hice nada" + intStorageDir;
        }

    }

}
```

---

**[getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))** es usado para crear un archivo o directorio en el almacenamiento externo ya que devuelve la ruta absoluta al directorio en el dispositivo de almacenamiento externo/compartido principal donde la aplicación puede colocar los archivos persistentes que posee.

Comment: Hola... Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta me sirvio bastante... He probado tu codigo y se guarda en:

/ROOT/Android/data/com.NombreAPP/files/LifeRegisterData

Lo que yo deseo es esto:

/Root/LifeRegisterData

Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Buena pregunta, anteriormente se podía, pero a partir de Android 10 se definió que no puedes crear archivos o directorios fuera de la estructura de la aplicación, únicamente podrás crear archivos o directorios dentro de : /....../Android/data/<package name>/files/ , no importa si usas getFilesDir()  o getExternalFilesDir() , es lo que comento en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/432306/95