# Creé una carpeta en el almacenamiento interno de android ¿Dónde la puedo visualizar?

Tags: java, android-studio, mkdir

Un saludo a la comunidad de stackoverflow en español, estoy trabajando con Android Studio y quiero crear una carpeta en el almacenamiento interno del telefono, se supone se crea la carpeta correctamente pero no logro visualizarla.
Adjunto mi código para crear la carpeta:

```
    // Crear la carpeta en la raíz del almacenamiento interno
    File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder");
    // Comprobar si la carpeta no existe. Entonces crearla
    if(!carpeta.exists()) {
        // carpeta.mkdir() creará el folder en la ruta indicada al inicializar el objeto File
        if(carpeta.mkdir())
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Carpeta creada: " + carpeta.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // Si la carpeta ya existe
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Carpeta existente: " + carpeta.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Log.d("Carpeta creada", carpeta.getAbsolutePath());
```

Gracias al Log obtuve la ruta en donde supuestamente se creo la carpeta, y este indica que se creo en :
**/storage/emulated/0/Folder**

Hasta donde entiendo: **storage/emulated/0**, emula el almacenamiento para mejorar la seguridad de  nuestra información. Teniendo eso en cuenta revise el almacenamiento interno de mi celular y no encuentro la carpeta. Y no tengo idea del porque no esta la carpeta, ¿O si esta, y no se como visualizarla?
Es por eso que escribo esta pregunta.

**Permisos del Manifest.XML**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Gradle**

```
android {
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lucky"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

**AGRADECERÍA SU AYUDA**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que [getExternalStorageDirectory() en Android API 29 en adelante esta marcado como un método obsoleto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417434/m%C3%A9todo-obsoleto-getexternalstoragedirectory-en-android-api-29-en-adelante) y precisamente ya no te permitirá crear archivos o directorio afuera de la estructura de directorios creada para la aplicación por lo tanto no será posible crear el directorio :

```
 /storage/emulated/0/Folder
```

ahora debes usar `getExternalFilesDir()` de esta forma:

```
//File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder");
File carpeta = new File( getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/Folder");
```

pero en este caso se creará el directorio dentro de la estructura de archivos de la aplicación:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/Folder
```

este es un cambio que realizó Google principalmente por seguridad.

---

No olvides que la [petición del permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` debe ser de forma manual](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24934/95).

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys, por la información, corregiré el error y comentare que fue lo que sucedió. Muchas gracias

Comment: Excelente @VictorManuel saludos!

Comment: Jorgesys, te agradezco la ayuda, funciono a la perfección tal y como lo mencionaste.