# getExternalFilesDir() crear carpetas

Tags: android

He tenido que rehacer el código de la creación de carpetas y ficheros al pasar mi app en Android 11 y API > 30.
Para ellos y crear carpetas y ficheros he utilizado `getExternalFilesDir()` y funciona bien, pero me lo crea aquí:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/Carpeta/fichero.pdf
```

y yo lo quiero crear aquí:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Carpeta/fichero.pdf
```

Es decir, en el directorio rais del almacenamiento del teléfono.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?
Gracias.

Comment: Ya no se permitirá crear archivos fuera de /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/ por cuestiones de seguridad, revisa mi respuesta Fernando.

Comment: Corrección, la carpeta raíz es `/`. A lo que te refieres es a la carpeta del usuario. Con el permiso **android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** puedes leer y escribir archivos en la carpeta del usuario. Más información:  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

Answer (score 2):

Es correcto el uso de `getExternalFilesDir()`  (`getExternalStorageDirectory()` es obsoleto y no debe usarse), pero ahora al usar `getExternalFilesDir()` tu archivo se creará dentro del directorio `/files` que a su vez se encuentra dentro del directorio definido en la estructura de directorios que se crea para la aplicación que sería:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/
```

**por seguridad ya no se permitirá crear archivos fuera de la estructura de directorios creados por la aplicación**, por lo tanto, no se podrán crear en esta ubicación:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Carpeta/
```

---

Revisa esta respuesta:

[Método obsoleto getExternalStorageDirectory() en Android API 29 en adelante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417434/m%C3%A9todo-obsoleto-getexternalstoragedirectory-en-android-api-29-en-adelante/432306#432306)

Comment: Muchas gracias. No es de mi agrado, ya que perdemos control sobre nuestra app, pero habrá que adaptarse. Yo lo preguntaba por si se podria crear en el directorio raiz, pero ya veo que no.

Comment: Por seguridad Android realizó cambios, también yo tuve que adaptarme a crear archivos únicamente en ese directorio :( , por cierto recuerda que si la respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema planteado, puedes marcarla como solución, revisa [tour], saludos.

Comment: OK. Pero ¿se puede grabar archivos o crear carpetas en Documents? Asi no tengo que ponerlo en /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/