# Error al guardar una imagen en la memoria externa

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de comprimir y después almacenar una foto en la memoria externa de un dispositivo Android con este método:

```
private String saveToExternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String nameImage, int compression) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/imagesDir";
    File file = new File(root, nameImage);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compression, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
Process: com.universitat_autonoma_de_barcelona_geology_mineralogy.minescope, PID: 13633
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.FileOutputStream.close()' on a null object reference
    at com.universitat_autonoma_de_barcelona_geology_mineralogy.minescope.Settings.saveToExternalStorage(Settings.java:219)
    at com.universitat_autonoma_de_barcelona_geology_mineralogy.minescope.Settings.access$100(Settings.java:39)
    at com.universitat_autonoma_de_barcelona_geology_mineralogy.minescope.Settings$3.run(Settings.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

¿Cómo puedo guardar las fotos en la sdcard?

Answer (score 3):

El problema indica que no puedes llamar el método  `fos.close();` , ya que el valor de `FileOutputStream` es null, esto se debe a que no podrás obtener el archivo en la ruta, puesto que estás usando `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` lo cual es incorrecto.

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/imagesDir";
```

**El uso de `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` es obsoleto**, revisa:

[**Método obsoleto getExternalStorageDirectory() en Android**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417434/m%C3%A9todo-obsoleto-getexternalstoragedirectory-en-android-api-29-en-adelante/432306#432306)

Debes cambiar a usar getExternalFilesDir() de esta forma:

```
String root = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/imagesDir";
```

pero ahora tu directorio donde podrás guardar u obtener tus imágenes será:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/imagesDir
```

No podrás leer o escribir en otro directorio, la razón es simplemente por cuestiones de seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es el try catch, deberias encapsular la declaracion de fos en el mismo y no por separado

```
private String saveToExternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String nameImage, int compression) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/imagesDir";
    File file = new File(root, nameImage);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compression, fos);
    finally {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```