# Excepción audio Firebase-> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/audio/media/49065: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, archivo, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy desarrollando en mi app la funcionalidad de que se puedan seleccionar de un recyclerview, una o varias canciones y subir estas canciones al storage de firebase. Pero al intentar subir cualquier archivo obteniendo la Uri de un archivo: var songFile = Uri.fromFile(File(it.contentUri))

Para subir la lista de canciones, lo realizo mediante un bucle, como lo tengo hecho aquí abajo->

```
    private fun uploadSongs(){
        selectedSongsList.forEach(){
            var songFile = Uri.fromFile(File(it.contentUri))
            val userMusicRef = storageReference.child((auth.currentUser.displayName.toString() + "/music/${songFile.lastPathSegment}"))

            var uploadTask = userMusicRef.putFile(songFile)
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
                checkUploadingSongs(false)
            }.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                checkUploadingSongs(true)
            }
        }

    }
```

Pero me sale la excepción de que "no ha encontrado el archivo", al subir el archivo de audio al "**storage**" de **Firebase**. La excepción ocurre justo cuando se realiza el ".putFile(songfile)".
(no creo que el problema sea que no existe el archivo o que la ruta del archivo esta mal, ya que esta misma ruta la he usado anteriormente con MediaPlayer para reproducir el archivo de audio, y se realiza sin ningún problema)

La Excepcion es la siguiente->

```
05-10 21:50:16.042 29830-29830/com.example.loops W/UploadTask: could not retrieve file size for upload file:///content%3A/media/external/audio/media/49065
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
        at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:270)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:200)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:986)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:844)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:798)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:118)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:240)
        at com.example.loops.fragments.songList.SongListFragment.uploadSongs(SongListFragment.kt:193)
        at com.example.loops.fragments.songList.SongListFragment.onMenuItemClick(SongListFragment.kt:144)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:154)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:975)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:623)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
05-10 21:50:16.042 29830-29830/com.example.loops E/UploadTask: could not locate file for uploading:file:///content%3A/media/external/audio/media/49065
05-10 21:50:16.042 29830-29830/com.example.loops E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
05-10 21:50:16.052 29830-29830/com.example.loops E/StorageException: /content:/media/external/audio/media/49065: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/audio/media/49065: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:709)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:131)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:240)
        at com.example.loops.fragments.songList.SongListFragment.uploadSongs(SongListFragment.kt:193)
        at com.example.loops.fragments.songList.SongListFragment.onMenuItemClick(SongListFragment.kt:144)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:154)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:975)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:623)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:709) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:131) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:240) 
        at com.example.loops.fragments.songList.SongListFragment.uploadSongs(SongListFragment.kt:193) 
        at com.example.loops.fragments.songList.SongListFragment.onMenuItemClick(SongListFragment.kt:144) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:154) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:975) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:623) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
05-10 21:50:16.052 29830-30337/com.example.loops E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
05-10 21:50:16.052 29830-30337/com.example.loops E/StorageException: /content:/media/external/audio/media/49065: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/audio/media/49065: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:709)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:131)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:240)
        at com.example.loops.fragments.songList.SongListFragment.uploadSongs(SongListFragment.kt:193)
        at com.example.loops.fragments.songList.SongListFragment.onMenuItemClick(SongListFragment.kt:144)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:154)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:975)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:623)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `putFile()` espera que le pases una uri de tipo `file`. El scheme de tu uri es `content` por eso no puede abrirlo. Una solución es abrir el archivo con un contentResolver y luego usar el inputStream para subirlo a cloud storage.

```
private fun uploadSongs() {
    selectedSongsList.forEach {
        val songUri = it.contentUri.toUri()
        val songStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(songUri)!!
        val userMusicRef = storageReference.child((auth.currentUser.displayName.toString() + "/music/${songUri.lastPathSegment}"))
        userMusicRef.putStream(songStream).addOnCompleteListener {
            checkUploadingSongs(it.isSuccessful)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, con el input stream me sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a el mensaje de error:

> could not retrieve file size for upload
> file:///content%3A/media/external/audio/media/49065
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory

Se tienen 2 causas que provocan este problema que son:

- El archivo no existe.
- No se tienen permisos para leer y escribir, recuerda que para Android 6.0 o mayor la petición de permisos de realizarse de forma manual.

La segunda causa seguramente es la más probable, asegura pedir el permiso  `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` , revisa:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external)