# MediaProvider: User 10536 does not have read permission on file android

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente problema al cargar archivos mediante api storage access framework, obtengo las uris pero no puedo leer los archivos
obtengo este error "MediaProvider: User 10536 does not have read permission on file "

si me pueden brindar su apoyo porfavor
este es el codigo

```
fun opendd(){
    val i=Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
        flags=Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    }
    startActivityIfNeeded(i, 33)
}
     
        //on result
      33 -> {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                data?.data?.also { uri ->
                   

                    val dfile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(applicationContext, uri)
                    val fileList = dfile!!.listFiles()
                    Log.d("usr", fileList.toString())
                    val jj = 1
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
                        
                        //se inicia un activity para mostrar la imagen en este caso
                        val i = Intent(this, AnimatedImageView::class.java)
                        i.data=  MediaStore.getMediaUri( this,fileList[9].uri)
                        startActivity(i)

                    }
                    }
                  
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: ¿Y pusiste los permisos en el Manifest?

Comment: Si, he puesto los permisos de lectura, pero en android 11 estos no funcionan

Comment: El si utilizo el permiso de acceso a todos los archivos el app funciona muy bien, pero para poder adaptarla a android 11, por politicas de google me niegan el permiso pese a la gran cantidad de archivos que lee y trabaja mi app, por lo que estoy estancado al no poder actualizarla ya que no he logrado encontrar una forma de que trabaje en android 11 sin este permiso

Answer (score 1):

"¿Y pusiste los permisos en el Manifest? – Si, he puesto los permisos de lectura, pero en android 11 estos no funcionan"

Actualmente además de definir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, también debes realizar la petición manual del mismo para poder usar este permiso.

Revisa:

[Petición permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24934/95)

Comment: Gracias por responder, los permisos los pido correctamente, el problema segun veo es que para android 11 ahora se requiere "manage al files", pero google rechaza este permiso para mi app, por lo que debo encontrar una manera de listar y leer archivos sin este permiso en android 11 en carpetas como android/media