# Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo una simple función de prueba para crear y compartir un archivo .csv que tras se ejecuta tras pulsar un botón. Al hacerlo me refleja el siguiente error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: qpon.csv: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:125)
        at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
        at com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.ui.history.HistoryBottomSheetDialog.exportCSV(HistoryBottomSheetDialog.kt:64)
        at com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.ui.history.HistoryBottomSheetDialog.onViewCreated$lambda-3(HistoryBottomSheetDialog.kt:55)
        at com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.ui.history.HistoryBottomSheetDialog.$r8$lambda$XOD8CuZgBTVKrUm_EEK1Lis60e0(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.ui.history.HistoryBottomSheetDialog$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     **Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)**
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7542)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236) 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:125) 
        at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63) 
        at com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.ui.history.HistoryBottomSheetDialog.exportCSV(HistoryBottomSheetDialog.kt:64) 
        at com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.ui.history.HistoryBottomSheetDialog.onViewCreated$lambda-3(HistoryBottomSheetDialog.kt:55) 
        at com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.ui.history.HistoryBottomSheetDialog.$r8$lambda$XOD8CuZgBTVKrUm_EEK1Lis60e0(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.ui.history.HistoryBottomSheetDialog$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onClick(Unknown Source:4) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Esta es la función:

```
private fun exportCSV(context: Context){
    val csvHeader = "first, second"
        val testFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".csv", context.cacheDir)
    var fileWriter = FileWriter("test.csv")

        fileWriter.append(csvHeader)
        fileWriter.append('\n')

        fileWriter.append("aaaaa")
        fileWriter.append(',')
        fileWriter.append("bbbbb")

        fileWriter.append('\n')
        fileWriter.close()

    val sendIntent = Intent()
    sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.fileprovider", testFile))
    sendIntent.type = "text/csv"
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SHARE"))

}
```

En el manifest tengo los permisos (también concedidos por el usuario) y el provider:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.ivandlrapp.virtualenconder.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Este es el documento files_paths.xml

```
<paths>
    <external-cache-path name="images" path="/"/>
    <cache-path name="docs" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

Obtengo el error en todas las versiones de Android.
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El problema se indica en el LogCat:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: qpon.csv: open failed: EROFS
> (Read-only file system)

Las causas son 2:

1. El archivo qpon.csv no existe o la ruta definida es incorrecta.
2. No se tiene definido y aceptado el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, recuerda que actualmente debes definir el permiso dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`.

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**pero es muy importante también implementar la petición manual ya que el usuario debe decidir si lo acepta o no.**

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Revisa: [Peticion permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24934/95)