# Error SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException al intentar acceder a base de datos SQLite

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sqlite

Tengo un proyecto que funcionaba, pero al cambiar de ordenador ya no funciona. Lo que hace simplemente es que al pulsar un botón, carga datos de una base de datos SQLite en pantalla, pero ahora de golpe me da el error SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException. Lo que hago es meter la base de datos manualmente en la memoria del dispositivo y al pulsar el botón la lee. Esta es la función que ejecuta la lectura y también he marcado dónde se produce el error:

```
    /**
     * Función que convierte a objetos los elementos de la base de datos y los mete en la lista
     */
    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private fun cargarPregunta(){
        // Conexión con la base de datos
        val admin = DBHelper(this)
        // AVISO: El error se produce en la siguiente linea y peta la app
        val db = admin.writableDatabase
        // Cursor donde se almacenan datos
        val cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Preguntas Order by Id desc", null)

        // Limpiamos la lista en caso de que contenga algo
        listaPreguntas.clear()

        // Se van convirtiendo los datos de la base de datos a objetos y se añaden a la lista
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                val id: Int = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id").toInt()).toInt()
                val pregunta: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Pregunta").toInt()), password)
                val respuesta1: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta1").toInt()), password)
                val respuesta2: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta2").toInt()), password)
                val respuesta3: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta3").toInt()), password)
                val respuesta4: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta4").toInt()), password)
                val respuestaCorrecta: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("RespuestaCorrecta").toInt()), password)

                val preguntaObject: Preguntas = Preguntas(id, pregunta, respuesta1, respuesta2, respuesta3, respuesta4, respuestaCorrecta)

                listaPreguntas.add(preguntaObject)
            }while(cursor.moveToNext())
        }

        miTextViewPregunta.setText(listaPreguntas.get(0).toString())

        // Cerramos conexiónes
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
    }
```

Este es el error al completo:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sqlite, PID: 9636
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:210)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:194)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:493)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:200)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:192)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:864)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:849)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:724)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:295)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:238)
    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity.cargarPregunta(MainActivity.kt:48)
    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:37)
    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$LaEDgNg3wrvgkcgrK81xnXd0Tt4(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
W/.example.sqlite: type=1400 audit(0.0:22): avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/com.example.sqlite/databases/Preguntas.sqlite" dev="dm-0" ino=15546 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
W/.example.sqlite: type=1400 audit(0.0:23): avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/com.example.sqlite/databases/Preguntas.sqlite" dev="dm-0" ino=15546 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Y aquí adjunto una imagen de dónde tengo la base de datos:

[image: Base de datos]

Gracias.

Comment: Cabe destacar que he vuelto a meter la base de datos, borrando la que ya había. También he sincronizado. Como digo, la app funcionaba en el ordenador donde empecé a desarrollarla pero lo formateé y ya no funciona.

Comment: Revisa los permisos y que el permiso de escritura sea aceptado.

Comment: Yo me encontré un problema similar y se resolvió **cambiando el nombre** de la base de datos. No me di cuenta de que al cambiar el modelo del SQLite (agregar una columna) debí haber incrementado a su vez la versión de la base de datos en Android. Tan solo probé a cambiar el nombre del archivo y sus referencias y funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not
> open database

esta relacionado a dos causas

**1)** no tienes aceptado el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` por lo tanto no puedes leer ni escribir en la base de datos.

Recuerda que actualmente debes definir el permiso en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

pero tambièn [**debes realizar la peticòn manual de este permiso**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24934/95).

**2)** La ruta de la base de datos es incorrecta. Aunque este punto no debe ser el problema ya que de acuerdo a tu imagen la ruta es correcta:

```
path="/data/data/com.example.sqlite/databases/Preguntas.sqlite"
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Pero me sigue dando el mismo error a pesar de pedir los permisos y aceptarlos. No entiendo qué está pasando ya que cuando empecé a desarrollar el proyecto funcionaba perfectamente pero al exportar e importar el proyecto en otro ordenador ya no funciona.

Comment: Cual es la linea 37 y 48 de MainActivity.kt ?