# Exportar datos de SQLite a CSV

Tags: java, android, android-studio

¿Tengo este método el cual debería exportar datos de la base de datos en un archivo .CSV, pero al implementarlo, sencillamente no hace nada ni manda error, ya di permisos en el manifiesto, los id del botón tienen el evento de presionar, y llamo al evento, que podría ser?

```
public void exportarCSV() {
        File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ExportarSQLiteCSV");
        String archivoAgenda = carpeta.toString() + "/" + "Usuarios.csv";

        boolean isCreate = false;
        if(!carpeta.exists()) {
            isCreate = carpeta.mkdir();
        }

        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(archivoAgenda);


            SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor fila = db.rawQuery("select * from datos", null);

            if(fila != null && fila.getCount() != 0) {
                fila.moveToFirst();
                do {

                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(0));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(1));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(2));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(3));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(4));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(5));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(6));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(7));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(8));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(9));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(10));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(12));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(13));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(14));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(15));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append(fila.getString(16));
                    fileWriter.append("\n");

                } while(fila.moveToNext());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Consulta.this, "No hay registros.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            db.close();
            fileWriter.close();
            Toast.makeText(Consulta.this, "SE CREO EL ARCHIVO CSV EXITOSAMENTE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
```

Comment: Super importante revisar el LogCat, de otra forma las causas son variadas!

Comment: Failed to read row 0, column 16 from a window with 6 rows, 16 columns                  use el debug y cuando presiono el boton arroja eso

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que además de definir en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, también debes [realizar la petición manual](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24934/95).

En este caso el problema es el uso del método [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()), este método es obsoleto para Android 10 (API level 29), es decir que si tienes orientada tu app para esta API o una versión posterior, tendras problemas para obtener este directorio aunque tengas el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` definido y aceptado manualmente.

La solución es cambiar a usar `getExternalFilesDir()`:

```
//File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ExportarSQLiteCSV");
File carpeta = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/ExportarSQLiteCSV");
```

Es importante saber que ahora solo podras crear y leer directorios dentro de la estructura de tu aplicación, es decir dentro de:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/
```

por seguridad, ya no se podrá escribir fuera de esta ubicación.

Comment: osea que el archivo .csv solo se podra guardar en android/data/com.paquete/files         File carpeta = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "Android/data/<paquete>/files/ExportarSQLiteCSV"); de esa manera?

Comment: coloque la linea tal cual pero aun asi crea el archivo...

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de generar el archivo csv, habian mas columnas que mostrar que en la base de datos, por eso no se creaba el archivo ni exportaba, publicare la tabla, el metodo de insercion y el metodo que crea el archivo.

la tabla datos:

```
 db.execSQL("create table datos (fecha TEXT ,departamento TEXT, municipio TEXT," +
            "vereda TEXT, finca TEXT, nombre TEXT, cedula TEXT primary key, telefono TEXT," +
            "visita TEXT, actividad TEXT, objeto TEXT, observaciones TEXT , firma1 TEXT , firma2 TEXT ,foto3 TEXT)");


el metodo de insercion de datos:

public Boolean insertarDatosHome(String fecha,
                                 String departamento,
                                 String municipio
                                , String vereda,
                                 String finca,
                                 String nombre,
                                 String cedula,
                                 String telefono,
                                 String visita,
                                 String actividad,
                                 String objeto,
                                 String observaciones,
                                 Bitmap firma1 ,
                                 Bitmap firma2,
                                 Bitmap img_foto ){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("fecha", fecha);
    valores.put("departamento", departamento);
    valores.put("municipio", municipio);
    valores.put("vereda", vereda);
    valores.put("finca", finca);
    valores.put("nombre", nombre);
    valores.put("cedula", cedula);
    valores.put("telefono", telefono);
    valores.put("visita", visita);
    valores.put("actividad",actividad);
    valores.put("objeto", objeto);
    valores.put("observaciones", observaciones);
    valores.put("firma1", String.valueOf(firma1));
    valores.put("firma2", String.valueOf(firma2));
    valores.put("foto3", String.valueOf(img_foto));

    long resultado = db.insert("datos",null,valores);
    if (resultado==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

metodo para crear el archivo csv con los datos y permiso de escritura, cabe recordar que hay que escribir tambien los permisos en el manifiesto:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
//FUNCION EXPORTAR EN CSV
public void exportarCSV() {
    File carpeta = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()+"/ExportarSQLiteCSV");
    String archivoAgenda = carpeta.toString() + "/" + "Usuarios.csv";

    boolean isCreate = false;
    if(!carpeta.exists()) {
        isCreate = carpeta.mkdir();
    }

    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(archivoAgenda);
        SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor fila = db.rawQuery("select * from datos", null);

        if(fila != null && fila.getCount() != 0) {
            fila.moveToFirst();
            do {

                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(0));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(1));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(2));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(3));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(4));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(5));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(6));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(7));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(8));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(9));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(10));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(11));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(12));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(13));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(fila.getString(14));



            } while(fila.moveToNext());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Consulta.this, "No hay registros.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        db.close();
        fileWriter.close();
        Toast.makeText(Consulta.this, "SE CREO EL ARCHIVO CSV EXITOSAMENTE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```