# Como aplicar la petición de permisos en runtime en Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Quiero solicitar permisos al usuario después de instalar la aplicación, cuando sean necesarios.

¿Es posible pedirlos desde la API actual (7.0) hasta la 19 (4.4)?

He leído la documentación y intentado cantidad de ejemplos pero todo es muy complejo y no consigo hacerlo funcionar. He visto plugins para la implementación pero tampoco me terminan de funcionar y preferiría no integrarlos.

Quisiera conseguir un código para pedir un permiso pero no consigo que nada lance la petición al usuario. La ventana no se muestra.

Agradecido de cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Solo se requiere pedir los permisos en runtime des de la versión 6.0 en adelante es decir Android Marshmallow+

Comment: Mirate está respuesta si funciona en xamarin http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13443/permisos-para-realizar-llamadas-compatible-con-android-6-0-y-versiones-anteriore