# ¿cómo pedir acceso a Internet por el usuario en android 6.0?

Tags: java, android

Cree una aplicación en Android, y la única opción de permiso que pedí fue

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

pero al momento de instalar mi apk con sistema operativo android 6.1, no me funciona y no me aparece la opción de permiso.

Answer (score 2):

**Pedir permisos solo a partir de 6.0:**

```
final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET = 0;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET);
        }
    }
}
```

**Recibir la respuesta del usuario:**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               System.out.println("El usuario ha aceptado los permisos");
            } else {
                System.out.println("El usuario ha rechazado los permisos");
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Fuente: [Permisos para realizar llamadas compatible con Android 6.0 y versiones anteriores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13443/permisos-para-realizar-llamadas-compatible-con-android-6-0-y-versiones-anteriore/13445#13445)

Comment: amigo no me sale :( solo aparece cargando mi aplicacion

Comment: Debes de pedir los permisos en el momento que lo necesites. ¿ A que te refieres con lo de solo aparece cargando mi aplicación?

Comment: pues mire mi aplicacion que hise es de mi pagina. pero lo muesto con un tabshost y solo aparece eso.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todoanimeshd11.solitario.todoanimeshd

Comment: aparte checo la opcion de permisio y me aparece como desabilitada no la puedo seleccionar, creo yo que no manda el mensaje que necesito. y aparte no funciona el manifest.per... tengo que ponerlo asi, android.manifest.per..

Comment: Deberías marcar la pregunta como duplicada