# ¿Cómo rellenar automáticamente un editText con el e-mail del usuario?

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una activity de registrar usuario y pues estaba pensando en que el editText de e-mail se rellenara automáticamente con el correo de gmail del teléfono.

En mis años ayudando a gente con sus teléfonos nuevos he notado que muchos no tienen ni idea de que su teléfono android usa un e-mail en su cuenta, así que pensaba en mi app consultar el e-mail del teléfono y ponerlo automáticamente en el editText.

Solo necesito poner el e-mail en una variable String.

Comment: Bienvenido Ayumu!, te sugiero revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas ya que fue marcada como demasiada amplia, considera agregar el código realizado. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la cuenta principal, podrías usar `AccountManager`, éste proporciona cuentas de muchos tipos, apps... Como te interesa únicamente un email, se podria hacer de dos formas las cuales dejare a continuación, una de ellas seria obtener el email principal "filtrando" aquellas cuentas que sean de gmail, el segundo ejemplo, por si la persona no tiene una cuenta gmail, se puede usar un `Pattern` para comprobar y cotejar si la cuenta es un email.

Cuenta principal gmail:

```
String email = "";
Account[] cuentas = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAccountsByType("com.google");
if(cuentas.length > 0) {
    email = cuentas[0].name;
}
```

Cuenta principal de cualquier tipo:

```
String email = "";
Account[] cuentas = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAccountsByType("com.google");
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
for (Account account : cuentas) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        email = account.name;
        break;
    }
}
```

La cuenta resultante la tendrás almacenada en la variable `email`, espero te sea de ayuda.

EDITO: Gracias a los que han comentado por recordarmelo, se me paso por alto mencionar el permiso que requieres.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Dicho permiso va situado en tu archivo `AndroidManifest`, si das soporte a versiones mas recientes de android, necesitas declarar los permisos en tiempo de ejecución, puedes ver un ejemplo en [este link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13443/permisos-para-realizar-llamadas-compatible-con-android-6-0-y-versiones-anteriore).

Comment: No es tan sencillo, no requiere permisos para obtener los datos del usuario?

Comment: @Israel te falto indicar los permisos en el manifest.

Comment: Gracias a ambos, a veces doy por hecho cosas tan obvias que se me olvida por completo agregarlas.