# Apk firmados y el testeo

Tags: android, android-studio, app

necesito resolver dudas a acerca de la firma de la app y diferentes incidencias que surgen.

Tengo una app modificada, y se tiene que re-subir a google play. Cuando hago pruebas mediante el emulador o por usb, no tengo problemas. Luego, he compilado como release y firmado (siempre con la misma key), pero me pone el error: "aplicación no instalada".

Luego he probado en compilar una version debugg, y esta se instala sin problemas en los terminales, pero por ejemplo falla la llamada directa (un servicio de soporte que ofrece). Esta misma llamada, si la hago desde una app instalada por USB, no me da problemas.

Entonces, vistas las circunstancias, no se si lo que ocurre es normal, o quizás estoy haciendo algo mal.

Resumen de mis dudas:

- ¿Es normal que no pueda instalar una app version release firmada en un móvil como app de tercero?
- ¿Si subo la versión release firmada en google play funcionará correctamente?
- En la versión debugg firmada no me deja realizar llamadas (pero si por usb). ¿Es eso lo qué debe ocurrir?

He pensado en subir una versión Beta de la app en Google Play con otro nombre, para probar la descarga y ver si funciona.

¡Gracias de antemano! :D

Comment: No entiendo muy bien las cosas que preguntas. *¿Es normal que no pueda instalar una app version release firmada en un móvil como app de tercero?* ¿a qué te refieres con *app de tercero*? *¿Si subo la versión release firmada en google play funcionará correctamente?* Si la has probado en un dispositivo y funciona correctamente, cuando la subas también funcionará. *En la versión debugg firmada no me deja realizar llamadas (pero si por usb)* No entiendo cuál es la diferencia entre *versión debugg firmada*  y *por usb*  ¿? Creo que debes ser más precioso planteando tus dudas, no entiendo ninguna.

Comment: ¿Cuando instalas la app en release en el movil hay alguna otra app instalada? Ya que si tienes una versión debug en el movil te puede dar problemas

Comment: Particularmente, si voy a probar una App lo que hago es, si la tengo instalada desde Play Store, borrar esa instalación e instalarla de nuevo desde Android Studio, haciendo las modificaciones y las pruebas pertinentes. Una vez terminada la actualización, compilarla en forma de `release` y subir la actualización a Play Store. Si por casualidad quiero probar algo de la App subida, elimino la que tengo en modo debug instalada y me descargo la de Play Store y pruebo lo que tengo que probar. No sé si tu confusión viene al querer tener instaladas las dos, la de Play Store y la de debug.

Answer (score 0):

Afortunadamente, una de las preguntas os la puedo responder. He conseguido la solución.

***En la versión debugg firmada no me deja realizar llamadas (pero si por usb). ¿Es eso lo qué debe ocurrir?***

Es un problema de permisos. Cuando haces pruebas por USB, pasa por alto los permisos (o los incluye de forma predeterminada) y no da error. Pero cuando se compila una versión debug, si que comprueba los permisos. En mi caso, aunque si estaban los permisos declarados como:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Daba problemas por motivos desconocidos. También he descubierto que es más práctico pedir permisos en el momento que se quiere realizar la acción (como pasa a partir de Android 6.0).

El caso curioso es que he intentado implementar lo que pone en la documentación:

Enlace: [1]: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419

Algo como esto:

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

Pero no funciona. He tomado un ejemplo de otro proyecto, y funciona a la perfección. Tengo curiosidad para saber el porque no funciona lo que pone en la propia documentación.

El código usado es este:

```
private void requestStoragePermissions() {
        withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        Intent Llamada = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        Llamada.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + UApp.soporteTel));
                        startActivity(Llamada);
                    }
                    @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, final PermissionToken token) {
                        new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .title(R.string.requested_permission)
                                .content(R.string.phone_permissions_required)
                                .positiveText(R.string.accept)
                                .onPositive((@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) -> {
                                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                                }).show();
                    }
                }).check();
    }
```

Lo importante ahora es el resultado. Si alguien sabe contestar a las demás preguntas sería de mucha gratitud :D

Comment: "pruebas por USB, pasa por alto los permisos (o los incluye de forma predeterminada) y no da error. Pero cuando se compila una versión debug si que comprueba los permisos"  , esto no debe ser diferencia, la versión debug me imagino la generas y la instalas desde un url pero es lo mismo si la subes vía USB , ambas seguramente se firman con el Keystore debug. Si una de ellas no requirió los permisos es porque ya los habías habilitado y si la otra los requirió es porque seguramente estaba eliminada la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Es normal que no pueda instalar una app version release firmada en un
>   móvil como app de tercero?

Si subes tu aplicación al emulador o la subes a tu dispositivo y posteriormente tratas de instalar tu aplicación firmada para "release", seguramente mostrara un mensaje el cual indica no se puede instalar puesto que en realidad se encuentra instala otra aplicación con una firma de "debug".

> ¿Si subo la versión release firmada en google play funcionará
>   correctamente?

Debe funcionar sin problema solo asegura que si usas alguna API esta este habilitada con el SHA-1 de tu firma con la cual realizaste tu .apk para release.

> En la versión debug firmada no me deja realizar llamadas (pero si por
>   usb). ¿Es eso lo qué debe ocurrir?

Cuando usas el emulador en realidad puede simular realizar llamadas pero este tipo de permisos [CALL_PHONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE) que es [considerado "peligroso"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) forzosamente debe requerirse en una aplicación para producción incluso si es una aplicación firmada con el certificado "debug".

---

En cuanto a este código, no se usa para solicitar permisos, se usa para determinar si tienes o no permisos, por lo cual obtienes -1 o -2, o si los permisos fueron asignados ( [PERMISSION_GRANTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/PermissionChecker.html#permission_granted)) por lo cual obtienes un valor de 0.

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

te sugiero revises:

[Requerir permisos para realizar llamadas.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13444/95)

```
 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas telefónicas.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso!");
    }
```