# Problema al crear archivo en SD

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas tardes a todos,

Tengo la intención de crear un pequeño programa que almacene en un archivo que almacene datos
desde un formulario.

Tipo :

```
insert into movimientos ('titulo','entidad','cantidad','fecha','operacion','descripcion') values
('compra','Supermercado',10.0,'15/05/2022','gasto','bla bla bla'),
```

El problema que tengo que es que no crea el archivo, al debuggear sale el siguiente error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/OfflineGestion/control.txt (No such file or directory)

Expongo todo el método onCreate donde compruebo si el archivo existe (funciona)

El problema lo tengo con el método crearArchivo(f_archivo); donde en la línea que corresponde al código

fr = new FileWriter(fileSt); salta directamente a la excepcion

```
  } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"No se pudo guardar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

**Lo he probado en eclipse y funciona perfectamente**, pero no con android studio y con el emulador del propio IDE.
```

Expongo las variables globales y el método OnCreate, más abajo el método crearArchivo() donde falla.

```
private String nombreArchivo = "control.txt";
private String nombreCarpeta = "OfflineGestion";

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control);

        File tarjeta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        f_carpeta = new File(tarjeta_sd.getAbsolutePath(),nombreCarpeta);
        //f = new File()
        if (!f_carpeta.exists()) {
            f_carpeta.mkdirs();
        }

        String pathArchivo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + nombreCarpeta + File.separator + nombreArchivo;
        //Si el archivo no existe, crear archivo con contenido básico


        f_archivo = new File(pathArchivo);
        if (!f_archivo.exists()) {
            crearArchivo(f_archivo);
        }

        sptitulo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sptitulo);
        //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the list
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tituloSpinner);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
        sptitulo.setAdapter(aa);


        edEntidad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entidad);
        edCantidad = findViewById(R.id.cantidad);
        initDatePicker();
        dateButton = findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        dateButton.setText(getTodayDate());
        edDescripcion = findViewById(R.id.edDescripcion);

        rbGasto = findViewById(R.id.rbGasto);
        rbIngreso = findViewById(R.id.rbIngreso);
        chExtra = findViewById(R.id.chExtra);
        chExtraEspecial = findViewById(R.id.chExtraEspecial);


    }
```

```
 private void crearArchivo(File f) {

        FileWriter fr = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        String fileSt = f.toString();
        try {

            fr = new FileWriter(fileSt);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fr);

            pw.println("insert into movimientos ('titulo','entidad','cantidad','fecha','operacion','descripcion') values");


            //fr.flush();

            Toast.makeText(this,"Guardado correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"No se pudo guardar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
             try {
                 if (null != fr) {
                     fr.close();
                 }
             } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
             }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que comentas se debe a dos causas:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/OfflineGestion/control.txt (No such file or directory)
```

1)El archivo no existe, como indica el error. En realidad tu còdigo crea el directorio y el archivo por lo tanto este no es el problema.

2)Debes definir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml y ademàs realizar la peticiòn manual del mismo para que puedas crear el archivo.

Revisa:

[Requerir permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13443/permisos-para-realizar-llamadas-compatible-con-android-6-0-y-versiones-anteriore/13445#13445)

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys,  En el manifest .xml tengo los permisos <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />--------Lo que me faltaba era el requerimiento manual que no explican en los cursos !!!! MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Funciona en el emulador, en el móvil no. La petición de permiso la he añadido al activity principal. No guarda el archivo -- int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para realizar ESCRIBIR EN SD.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
        } else {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso!");
        }

Comment: El requerimiento manual debe funcionar tanto en el emulador como en el dispositivo, tal vez ya tienes el permiso en el dispositivo.

Comment: He desinstalado la aplicación en el móvil, añadido el requerimiento también en la siguiente activity para que chequee si existe el permiso. Nada más iniciar la aplicación me pregunta si "Allow" o "Deny", Le doy a "Allow". Y tampoco funciona en el móvil. Al ir a Administrar permisos en el móvil en storage, apararece la aplicación. No veo que la carpeta creada en la SD